# Unique identifier with smallest base possible, without collisions on old/new set of data

Tags: javascript, typescript, uniqueidentifier

I receive one or more trees of nodes.

Nodes may, or may not have ID properties on them.

Currently I am iterating through the tree and adding random 8 digit numbers on nodes which do not have ID property. As I do not expect more than 10k nodes in the trees chance of having collisions is very small.

Still I am considering how best to reduce the length of the IDs to maybe 4 digits while making sure there are no collisions within one tree. What comes to my mind is to iterate once through the tree gathering existing IDs into a Set and than again adding new IDs while checking against the Set that there are no collisions. Set would have to be reset for each tree.

I would appreciate your opinion on this matter and advice if there are more performant ways of achieving this.

Appendix A:

I am considering following (simplified 0-9) issue. If I have a Set of existing IDs `[0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 9]` I would have to generate random numbers until I get e.g. 4 (no collision) which I am concerned would be a bit slow on a larger Set and surely not the optimal route.

Comment: It's a tree.  Wouldn't you know at the time of insertion whether you're duplicating an existing node or not?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I receive a tree where some nodes have while others do not have IDs. I'd like for all to have UniqueIDs.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question.  How did your existing tree know where to put each node?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not have information on how these trees were originally built. By using IDs I can easily add children/siblings.

Comment: Why don't you just walk your existing tree and build a new one?

Comment: People spend years polishing the solution of unique id generation problem.  I would look at https://github.com/ai/nanoid#js   Even if you prefer crafted solution, I guess you might find some inspiration looking how they did it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but they I would lose IDs of the old one and there might be some modules that I am not aware of that use them.

Comment: Can't you just make some simple counter variable? And when you need it, then just increase the counter by one and use it as an ID?

Comment: I don't propose that you throw out your old IDs, only that you replace the missing ones.

Comment: @MateuszSamsel I am considering something like that but that would mean overwriting existing IDs might be connected to some history/logs so I am not sure it is the best approach.

Comment: @radulle if you need to preserve old ID then simplest approach would be store already used ID in some Array or Set. Then for every node which doesn't have ID you take the number form the counter. In case that number is in used one just increment until you find first free one.
You could wrap it in some abstraction like generators or iterators, to hide those counters and arrays or alternatively wrap it inside some function. But it depends on your project if you need a fast and simple solution or pretty one.

Comment: @MateuszSamsel I will probably go down this road and due to performance have to go with a counter which would be determened by the max value I receive from existing Tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a really simple approach which will generate for you an array of not used numbers with a given MAX range.

```js
const MAX = 30;
const usedNumbers = [3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 16, 23, 27];

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n
const notUsedNumbers = Array.from(Array(MAX), (_, i) => i+1).filter(i => !usedNumbers.includes(i));

console.log(notUsedNumbers);
```

And link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9r6anq1/

Comment: This is an interesting, albeit hard to read and on larger ranges extremely slow, almost unusable solution.

Comment: @radulle what do you mean by extremely slow? 4 digit numbers are max `10000` and from the fast test, in my browser, it takes like 25 - 40 milliseconds to execute it. https://jsfiddle.net/x39L0utm/1/ What performance would you like to have?

Comment: When I tried to run it it took much more and Chrome got hung, I will have to recheck, still if I were to go down this path I would have to do it once per tree and than keep that array in memory and shifting it when needed.

Comment: Maybe it's not the ID generation a real problem but some additional operation which you perform on the nodes? I encourage you to play with [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) to precisely measure the execution time of part of your code.
Anyway if you don't want to duplicate IDs, then you need to store somewhere already used ones and compare if ID which you already take is taken or not.Or you need to overwrite all ID according to your needs so you will know there is no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

10^8 possibilities with random selection means you have a 50% chance of collision with only 10^4 objects (see Birthday Paradox); that is not "very small" odds. Reducing that to only 10^4 possibilities with 10^4 objects means collisions will approach 100% as you get toward the end and, if you ever have 10k+1 objects one day, will never terminate.

In general, if you want to use a relatively short ID space, you're going to need a very efficient conflict detection system, e.g. keeping all assigned (or not assigned) values in a scratchpad, or just give up on randomly assigning values and go sequentially.