# function that returns an array with all the numbers from 1 to 255

Tags: javascript, arrays

can you help me with this code? I'm new here, I'm still lost how to write code here.

```
    function get_array(){
    var arr [];
`enter code here`
return arr[];
```

}

Comment: [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352604)

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = new Array(255).fill(0).map((el, i) => i + 1);
```

Comment: Hello, can you help me, is this javascript? what is it fill and map(el)

Comment: it is javascript my friend:)
I just created an empty array of size 255 and filled it with zeros just so i can iterate over it. then I used the current index plus 1 as the value of the new array in that index.
(map function returns a new array)