# how to render divs dynamically based on the number of items

Tags: reactjs

I want to show slideshow circle buttons dynamically based on the **number** of slides I will get from the server. I couldn't do it with loops since I have a number of slides predefined & no array. How can I show my buttons? Now I manually created 4 buttons. (I deleted unnecessary code so that only important snippets are present).

```js
import React = require("react");

type NavigationEvent = "Backward" | "Forward" | "Pause" | "Play";

interface Props {
    slidesAmount: number;
    activeSlideIndex: number;
}

function SlideshowCarouselNavigationBarComponent(props: Props) {
const onPlayButtonClicked = () => {
        props.navigate("Play");
    }

    const onPauseButtonClicked = () => {
        props.navigate("Pause");
    }

    const onSlideButtonClicked = index => {
        props.navigateToIndex(index);
    }

return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div className={classes.dotsContainer}>
                    <div className={classes.dots}>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.dots}>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.dots}>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.dots}>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export = SlideshowCarouselNavigationBarComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (it is the most concise and understable way that I found out) : Iterating `slidesAmount` times, in order to display the circles:

```
<div className={classes.dotsContainer}>
    {[...Array(props.slidesAmmount)].map((_)=>(
       <div className={classes.dots}>
       </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: I had to create a new Array and pass it my items, but in the return your code worked, thanks!

Comment: Ah, i didn't understood that you had item to iterate over

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.fill() This will create array of preidentified length filled with unidentified values

```
new Array(props.slidesAmmount).fill().map((v, i){
   return <div> .... </div>
});
```

please see [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n) for more detailed answers