# Create an alert when data filled

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a small project for my own use and come to this. I need to fill data for current sheet (column A). When it's done, a "done" alert should appear.
Here is my gs code:

```
function fillData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
   ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 1).setValue(i);
 }
}

function done(){
 Browser.msgBox("done");
}

function doIt(){
 fillData();
 done();
}
```

However, the alert seems to appear before filling data done! How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` to complete the pending sheet changes so the message can appear after the sheet changes:

```
function doIt(){
   fillData();
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   done();
}
```

If this does not work consistently then try to use `sleep`, again between `fillData` and `done`, e.g. `Utilities.sleep(3000);` to wait for example for 3 seconds.

### Bonus Information / Optimal Solution:

- Unfortunately, the current approach is not efficient because it is iteratively calling Google Apps Script methods like `getRange` and `setValue` which is a very slow and time consuming approach.
- Also, you don't need a `for` loop for this purpose. There are solutions in StackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352604/11225291) which can return an array of 1000 elements between 1 and 1000.

Work with the arrays instead:

```
function fillData() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 const as = ss.getActiveSheet();
 const N = 1000; // Choose the number of elements to add
 const ar = Array.from({length: N}, (_, i) => i + 1).map(r=>[r]);
 as.getRange(1,1,N,1).setValues(ar);
}
```

and use the version of `doIt` in my answer (with `flush` included).

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly try to just place an if statement right when you hit 999?

```
function fillData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
   ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 1).setValue(i);
   
   if (i == 999) {

   Browser.msgBox("done");

   }
 }
}
```