# Printing multiplication table with 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multiplication

I'm a really beginner and for now im preparing for JavaScript bootcamp. Unfortunately i stuck with one of pre-work excercises.

My task is to do muliplication table, put it into empty 2D Array and print it precisely in this form:

```
1 x 1 = 1 | 1 x 2 = 2 | 1 x 3 = 3
2 x 1 = 2 | 2 x 2 = 4 | 2 x 3 = 6
3 x 1 = 3 | 3 x 2 = 6 | 3 x 3 = 9
```

On start I have 2 var declared:
const n = 3;
const calc = [];

I know i have to start with 'for' loop - and i have no idea whats next;

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
}

EDIT:
Thanks for help, correct code below:

```
const n = 3;
const calc = [];


for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    calc[i] = [];
    for(let k = 0; k < n; k++){
        calc[i][k] = (i + 1) + ' * ' + (k + 1) + ' = ' + (i + 1) * (k + 1);
    }
}
for(let i = 0; i < calc.length; i++){
    console.log(String(calc[i]).replaceAll(',', ' | '));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two 'for' loops to fill the array in 2D. After that you need another 'for' loop to print each row (for example in a paragraph tag).

**Working example:**

```js
const n = 3; 
const calc = [];

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    calc[i] = [];         //add the inner arrays (the second dimension)
    for(k = 0; k < n; k++){ 
        calc[i][k] = (k + 1) + ' x ' + (i + 1) + ' = ' + (k + 1) * (i + 1);
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < calc.length; i++){ 
    const p = document.createElement("p");
                          //convert each inner array to a string
    p.innerHTML = String(calc[i]).replaceAll(',', ' | ');
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much, it works! Now I have to try to understand whats happened there:)

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Can I Ask U one more question? I dont understand what does this line: calc[i] = []; if this pushes incremented "i" value into array?

Comment: It adds the inner arrays (the second dimension) that are indexed in the inner 'for' loop with 'k'. I will comment the code...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with...

```
n = 3;
// create table array
table = [];
for(row=0; row<n;row++){
    // generate an array for each row
    table.push([])
    for(col=0; col<n;col++){
        // add the multiplication to each column in the row
        // Notice that the column and row numbers start at zero in an array so 1 is added before multiplying
        table[row].push((col+1) + ' x ' + (row+1) + ' = ' + (col+1)*(row+1));
    }
}
// print the array to the console for fun
console.log(table);
// go through each row in table array, convert it to a string and replace ',' with ' | ' and printing it to the log
// Notice that in the replace argument you have to use /,/g instead of ',' in order to replace all commas and not just the first one
for(row=0; row<table.length;row++){ 
    console.log(String(table[row]).replace(/,/g, ' | '))
}
```

I have added a bit of commenting. Hopefully you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I would write to solve your problem.

```js
function generate(num, fn) {
  var a = Array(num), b = 0;
  while (b < num) a[b] = fn(b++);
  return a;
}
const table = (num, fn, separator) => generate(num, fn).join(separator);
const entry = (a, b) => `${a} x ${b} = ${a * b}`;
const result = table(3, row => table(3, col => entry(row + 1, col + 1), ' | '), '\n');

console.log(result);
```

**generate** returns an array like `[fn(0), fn(1), fn(2), ..., fn(num-1)]`.  There's more than one way to do this but what I provided here is [pretty quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n).

**table** calls *generate*, but with the elements joined together into a string with a separator between them.

**entry** formats the text of one entry in the table like: `2 x 3 = 6`

The result is a table of tables (a two-dimensional table) with `|` delimiting the columns and `\n` delimiting the rows.

#### Note:

If you insist on having a complete 2D array, you could defer the joins until later like this, *but it's slower*:

```js
function generate(num, fn) {
  var array = Array(num), i = 0;
  while (i < num) array[i] = fn(i++);
  return array;
}
const entry = (a, b) => `${a} x ${b} = ${a * b}`;
const array2d = generate(3, row => generate(3, col => entry(row + 1, col + 1)));
const result = array2d.map(row => row.join(' | ')).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1 Loop for Rows and 1 Loop for Columns

OP wasn't specific about what said output of the multiplication table should be in -- HTML, text, ponies...?

A table can be generated by an outer loop and an inner loop:

1. The outer loop generates an array rows of a table.
   `[row 1, row 2, row 3]`
2. The inner loop generates an array of cells (forming a column) for each row.
   `[col  1, col 2, col 3]`
3. So a 2D array looks like one or more arrays within an array.
   `[ row 1[col 1, col 2, col 3], row 2[col 1, col 2, col 3], row 3[col 1, col 2, col 3] ]`

The example below is a function that will pass a number (`num`) through and return a table with the same amount of rows and columns as the parameter passed (`num`). Each cell will contain the text of a simple formula:

> `row number * col number = X`

Each `col` is delimited by a pipe `|`, and each `row` is delimited by a new line.

Details are commented in Snippet

```js
// Pass a number [num]
function mTable(num) {
  // Declare [row] array [rData]
  const rData = [];
  // for each [row] until [num] is reached...
  for (let row = 1; row <= num; row++) {
    //... declare [col] array [cData]...
    const cData = [];
    //... then for each [col] until [num] is reached...
    for (let col = 1; col <= num; col++) {
      //... generate the text✱ repesenting the product of the row and column numbers...
      const cell = `${row} X ${col} = ${row*col}`;
      //... next, push it to the [cData] array
      cData.push(cell);
    }
    // Once the [cData] is created, convert it into a formatted line of text delimited by pipes '|'
    const data = cData.join(' | ');
    // Push the [cData] array into the [rData] array
    rData.push(data);
  }
  // After the last [cData] array is pushed into the [tData] array, output [tData] as a formatted line of text delimited by new lines✱
  return rData.join(`
`);
}

// Generate a 3x3 table 
console.log(mTable(3));

// Generate a 8x8 table
console.log(mTable(8));

/* 
✱The special syntax wrapped in grave ticks `...` is called template literals see References
*/
```

### References

- [**for** Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [**.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [**.join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks for helpful comments, it helps me a lot!