# How to map sequentially numbered properties of object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that represents an E-Commerce Item.

In addition to normal properties like `item.name`, `item.number` and `item.price`, each item has 20 metadata properties. *i.e.*  `item.metadata1Active`, `item.metadata1Name` and `item.metadata1` etc.

I need to do a loop of some type over each property named `metadataXActive` and if true display the corresponding/matching `metadataXName` and `metadataX` properties.

I have the first 10 displaying without a loop:

```
function unflatten(item) {          
    return (
        <div className="metabox">
            {item.metadata1Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata1Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata1}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata2Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata2Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata2}</label></p>) : null }
            {item.metadata3Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata3Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata3}</label></p>) : null }
            {item.metadata4Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata4Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata4}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata5Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata5Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata5}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata6Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata6Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata6}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata7Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata7Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata7}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata8Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata8Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata8}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata9Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata9Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata9}</label></p>) : null}
            {item.metadata10Active === true ? (<p><label className="metadata">{item.metadata10Name}</label>: <label className="metadata">{item.metadata10}</label></p>) : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know there are 20 metadata properties, you can just [iterate 20 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n) and check each using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
function unflatten(item) {

  return (
    <div className='metabox'>
      {[...Array(20).keys()].map((i) => (
        item[`metadata${i+1}Active`] === true
          ? (<p key={`metadata${i+1}Name`}>
            <label className='metadata'>{item[`metadata${i+1}Name`]}</label>:{' '}
            <label className='metadata'>{item[`metadata${i+1}`]}</label>
          </p>)
          : null
      ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Like the answer in this stack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/12792486

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new `Object.hasOwn` method which checks if the specified object has the indicated property as its own property. If the property is inherited, or does not exist, the method will return false.

```
if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'propertyName')){
  // do stuff
}
```

More about `Object.hasOwn` -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn

Comment: Still a lot of red: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=hasOwn).

Answer (score 0):

If your object item has only metadaXActive props I would suggest this

```
function unflatten(item) {          
return (
    <div className="metabox">`
      {{
    for (const metadata in item) {
     item[metadata] === true ?
       // here if true.           
       :
       // here if false
       }
      }}
    </div>
```