# How to loop React Elements for a specific amount of times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, jsx, array-map

I am trying to make a looper component so that I can loop any of its children for a specific amount of time.
How can I do that?

```
// Looper

function Looper({ children, array }) {
    return (
      <div>
        {array.map((item) => (
          <div key={item}>{children}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  

// It works, but it needs a dummy array that I don't want.

<Looper array={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}>
    <span>Hello Guys..</span>
</Looper>
```

Comment: Why not `[...Array(5)].map((_,idx) => (<div key={idx} ..`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array of incrementing numbers on the fly using `[...Array(times).keys()]`, like so:

```
// Looper

function Looper({ children, times }) {
    const keys = [...Array(times).keys()];
    return (
      <div>
        {keys.map((item) => (
          <div key={item}>{children}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
<Looper times={5}>
    <span>Hello Guys..</span>
</Looper>
```

Comment: You can mix up creating your array with other ways as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n

But this is the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

replace your map function with a for loop and pass a count i:e number of times you want the looper to render, and use that index as a key for the child divs then push them into an array. Finally, return that array of child divs. Check out this link if you want to go with this approach [Loop inside React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx)