# How can I optimise long if statements and make better code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm learning JS and I want make my own small app where I store many random unique numbers in arrays. My
code works fine but I want to make many arrays and I have problems with big if conditionals for example:

```
if ( !num[0].includes(number) && !num[1].includes(number) && !num[2].includes(number) && !num[3].includes(number) )
```

I spent some time searching similar examples and couldn't figure out how to optimise my code. How can I make my code better?
Thanks in advance :-)

```js
const nums = [];
const N = 4;
for(let i=0; i<N; i++){
    nums[i] = [];
}
const uniqueNumber = function(minValue, maxValue){
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxValue-minValue+1)+minValue);
    if (!nums[0].includes(number)) {
        nums[0].push(number);
        return number;
    } else if (nums[0].length - 1 !== maxValue) {
        uniqueNumber(minValue, maxValue);
    }
}
const uniqueNumber_2 = function(minValue, maxValue){
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxValue-minValue+1)+minValue);
    if ( !nums[0].includes(number) && !nums[1].includes(number) ) {
        nums[1].push(number);
        return number;
    } else if (nums[1].length - 1 !== maxValue) {
        uniqueNumber_2(minValue, maxValue);
    }
}
const uniqueNumber_3 = function(minValue, maxValue){
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxValue-minValue+1)+minValue);
    if ( !nums[0].includes(number) && !nums[1].includes(number) && !nums[2].includes(number) ) {
        nums[2].push(number);
        return number;
    } else if (nums[2].length - 1 !== maxValue) {
        uniqueNumber_3(minValue, maxValue);
    }
}
const uniqueNumber_4 = function(minValue, maxValue){
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxValue-minValue+1)+minValue);
    if ( !nums[0].includes(number) && !nums[1].includes(number) && !nums[2].includes(number) && !nums[3].includes(number) ) {
        nums[3].push(number);
        return number;
    } else if (nums[3].length - 1 !== maxValue) {
        uniqueNumber_4(minValue, maxValue);
    }
}
const min = 10;
const max = 90;
const howMany = (max-min)/N;
for(let i=0; i<howMany; i++){
    uniqueNumber(min, max);
}
for(let i=0; i<howMany; i++){
    uniqueNumber_2(min, max);
}
for(let i=0; i<howMany; i++){
    uniqueNumber_3(min, max);
}
for(let i=0; i<howMany; i++){
    uniqueNumber_4(min, max);
}
const numsH2 = [];
for(let i=0; i<N; i++){
    numsH2[i] = "<h2>Array " + i + "</h2>";
}
for(let i=0; i<N; i++){
    if(i == N-1){
        document.getElementById("pNumbers").innerHTML +=  numsH2[i] + nums[i] + "<br>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("pNumbers").innerHTML += numsH2[i] + nums[i] + "<br><br><hr><br>";
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: "Courier New",monospace;
}
#numbers{
    width: 443px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#numbers h1{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#numbers p{
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#numbers h2{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#pNumbers {
    background: rgb(235 249 255);
}
hr{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #b7d0e2;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random arrays</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="numbers">
        <h1>Unique numbers in Arrays</h1>
        <p id="pNumbers"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also you should only need one uniqueNumber function not 5, work out the single difference and pass a param or callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Write functions

#### random integer in inclusive range

First of all, let's get that [*inclusive bounds random number*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) calculation into its own function.

```
const getRandomInt = (min, max) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

#### set of unique numbers

And next, let's make use of `Set` to avoid all your *"do I have one of these yet"* checks to create your array of random numbers.  Just keep adding random numbers into your set until it has the desired number of elements.  A Set can be *spread* back to an Array.  **Beware**, this version doesn't attempt to avoid endless loops or protect against invalid arguments such as what happens when N is zero.

```
const uniqueNumbers = (min, max, N) => {
  const howMany = (max - min) / N;
  const set = new Set();
  while (set.size < howMany) set.add(getRandomInt(min, max));
  return [...set];
}
```

#### an array of N things

And lastly you'll want a way to make an array of *n* things where the thing is defined by a function.  There are [numerous ways of accomplishing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n), but [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is almost exactly what you need, you just need to pass it an object that defines a `length` property.

```
const arrayOfN = (length, fn) => Array.from({ length }, fn);
```

### Use your functions

Armed with those 3 things, you can much more concisely write your code to generate an array of 4 such sets of unique numbers.

```
const min = 10;
const max = 90;
const N = 4;
const nums = arrayOfN(4, () => uniqueNumbers(min, max, N));
```

Working example below:

```js
const getRandomInt = (min, max) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

const uniqueNumbers = (min, max, N) => {
  const howMany = (max - min) / N;
  const set = new Set();
  while (set.size < howMany) set.add(getRandomInt(min, max));
  return [...set];
}

const arrayOfN = (length, fn) => Array.from({ length }, fn);

const min = 10;
const max = 90;
const N = 4;
const nums = arrayOfN(4, () => uniqueNumbers(min, max, N));

console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generalize the function by making a third parameter indicating how many indicies to search up to. Then you can `.slice` the `nums` array to extract all subarrays to check, and if they pass an `.every` test, push to the last one.

```
const uniqueNumber = function (minValue, maxValue, maxSubarrayIndex) {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue + 1) + minValue);
    const subarrays = nums.slice(0, maxSubarrayIndex + 1);
    if (subarrays.every(subarr => !subarr.includes(number))) {
        nums[maxSubarrayIndex].push(number);
    } else {
        uniqueNumber(minValue, maxValue, maxSubarrayIndex);
    }
}
```

This can then replace all of the functions, eg instead of doing

```
uniqueNumber_3(2, 5)
```

you can do

```
uniqueNumber(2, 5, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I made simple outer for loop and implemented your function. Now I have to learn more about "slice" and "every" functions.