# Get all days from a month

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I wish to have all the days from the current month in an array. For example this month (April 2022) has 30 days so I wish to have an array of integers like so:

```
const monthDays = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 , 30 ]
```

My attempt :

```
Array.from(Array(moment('2022-04').daysInMonth()).keys())
```

And the output is :

```
//  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

I have and idea how moment works and `0` is always the first day or the first month , but how can i achieve the result that i want from the example above

So basically `moment` will generate automatically this array if I fetch the current month. How can we achieve that?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck?

Comment: Do you know how to get the number of days? How to create an array of a given length?

Comment: @PandaMastr, Try like `Array.from(Array(moment('2022-04').daysInMonth()).keys()).map(i => i + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create moment object
2. Set the month to the desired month
3. Use [`daysInMonth()`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/10-days-in-month/) to get the number of days
4. [Create an array from `1` to the result of step 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n)

```js
const mom = new moment();
mom.set('month', 3); // 0-indexed, so 3 --> 4 --> April

const daysInApril = mom.daysInMonth();
const aprilDays   = Array.from({length: daysInApril}, (_, i) => i + 1);

console.log(aprilDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```