# Index elements with a certain class and ignore all other siblings

Tags: jquery

```html
<div class="collection">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How would I get the index of the divs with class "selected" to ignore the other siblings? in this case it should return 0 1 2, and not 1 3 5.

Comment: Index relative to what? The index of the divs with class "selected" relative to the "collection"-div are exactly 1, 3 and 5. Also what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Pass a selector to `index()` which is the set you want to find the index of the current element within. eg: `$(this).index('.selected')`

Comment: _"in this case it should return 0 1 2"_ - what is "it"? What exactly are you trying to call, and in what context? Maybe you should just use `$('.item.selected').length` to figure out that there _are_ three of those items ... and if you really _need_ an array containing the numbers 0, 1 and 2 based on that, create it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352604/1427878

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm basically using this function to hide/show divs and assign a class on the shown divs to limit them, but because there would be other divs with indexation I'm trying to index only the selected ones to hide them above a specific number for a "load more" button. Rory's idea worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Rory McCrossan wrote, use a selector for the `index()` method:

```js
index('.selected')
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('.selected').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).index('.selected'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="collection">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```