# How spread operator working here with Array keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Could someone explain how this `[...Array(10).keys()];` working and logging 0 to 9 index?

```js
console.log([...Array(10).keys()]);
```

Comment: Do you know what [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) does? I am not sure what part you are not sure about.

Comment: so you want the result to be [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] ?

Comment: Well, you're not using the `num1` argument...

Comment: @epascarello
Yes i know how keys() works

Comment: So it takes the iterator and converts it into an array. Still not sure what you are looking for in an answer.

Comment: i want to know how that spread and key working together
@Amaarockz

Comment: That was typo mistake @HereticMonkey

Comment: Keys returns an iterator that has the values of 0-9 and the spread takes the iterator and converts those values into an array. Quicker way of making an array for increasing numbers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n

Comment: keys() basically return the indices of the Array(10) as an iterator, the square brackets then converts the iterator into 'list'. learn more [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation

Case-1

```
const string = 'hello';

const array = [...string];

array;
// [ 'h' , 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' ]
```

Case-2

Where we see spread operator acting as an eraser

```
[
  ...[1, 2, 3] // The dots erases the brackets
]

/*  Becoming this: */
[
  1, 2, 3 // "Erased"
]
```

Combining both of the above cases will help you on whats happening