# Identifier expected JSX for loop Eslint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

im new to react and try to build some code in JSX. but when i trying to automate the  tags using for loop it give me a Eslint error.

```
<table className="TableData">

    
    
let num= 9;



  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>


       for(let i=0; i <num; i++){
        return <th> {i+1}</th>;
        } 
     

      <th>Win</th>
      <th>Lose</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach to render some JSX for each item in an array is to use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

If you only have a number but no array, you can still create an array with `new Array(9).fill(null)`

```
export default function App() {
  let num = 9;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table className="TableData">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            {new Array(num).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
              return <th>{i}</th>;
            })}
            <th>Win</th>
            <th>Lose</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cool-snow-7hn5tq]

Answer (score 0):

First, using `return` inside the for loop will exit the for loop.

Check here how to create the array: [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n)

You can try something like this:

```
const num = 9;
const foo = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
   foo.push(<th>{i+1}</th>);
}
```

And then insert it inside JSX:

```
<th>Week</th>
   {foo}
<th>Win</th>
```