# how to add numbers on my array until i reached my value?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a maximum of quantity on a value and i want to see all the number on my dropdown

for exemple my quantity is

const quantity= 10

i want to create a function which pushed [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] on an array.

I'm working with react native

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1)`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also a massive dupe

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: [Massive dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n)

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

```
    function createArray(len){
      let arr = [] 
      for(let i = 0 ; i < len;i++){
        arr.push(i + 1);
      }
      return arr
    }
    
    let qty = 10
    console.log(createArray(qty))
```

Comment: Why not `let arr = [];  for(let i = 1 ; i <= len;i++) arr.push(i + 1); return arr }`