# shorthand to create a numbered array of objects for react select in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-select

is there a shorthand approach to creating an array of objects of length X in js other than using a for loop? This is to use for react select npm package

end result

```
const options = [
  { value: 1, label: "1" },
  { value: 2, label: "2" },
  { value: 3, label: "3" },
];
```

for loop approach

```
let options = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { // assume arbitrary length 10
    options.push({
        value: i,
        label: i.toString()
    })
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n)

Comment: You might be able to use `map` or `forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[...Array(number).keys()].map(i => ({ value: i + 1, label: (i + 1).toString() }))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from()` with a mapping function to creat your objects:

```
const res = Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => ({value: i+1, label: (i+1).toString()}))
```

This creates the array and fills it with the appropriate objects in the one iteration (rather than performing multiple iterations)