# How can I create an array containing 1...X without loop

Tags: javascript

how creating a JavaScript array containing 1 through to x where x is only known at runtime without the loop.

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
   arr.push(i);
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: `Array.from({ length: X }, (_, i) => i + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n) issue

here is the answer anyway

```
const arr = [...''.padEnd(N)].map((_,i)=>i+1)
```

Comment: Once you've reached 3k rep, you can vote to close as duplicate. For now, this should be a comment.