# RangeError: Invalid array length while i test my angular code

Tags: angular, unit-testing, user-interface, frontend

Code is working properly there is no issue on that, but While I test my angular code I got this following error.

what i have to add to get rid of this error. anyone please help me on this. i know array size get exceeded but how to fix that?
**RangeError: Invalid array length**

[image]

component.ts

```
 this.columns = Array.from(Array(this.nbColumn - 1 > 0 ? this.nbColumn - 1 : 0 ).keys())
```

spec.ts

```
describe('HomeComponent', () => {
      let component: HomeComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
    
      beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports:[HttpClientModule,RouterTestingModule,MatSnackBarModule],
          declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
          providers:[ ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

Edited:
I have added my spec file

Comment: can you show your unit test (spec) file ? As suggested, you may have mismocked some values.

Comment: @Random I have added my spec file. can you please check

Comment: Indeed, your unit test is empty. `detectChanges` will run your `ngOnInit`. You have to mock all your services so their method return a specific value, which would allow the `ngOnInit()` method to run without errors.

Comment: @Random , thanks for your feedback .As i am new to angular , can you please help me with add some example

Comment: Sorry, but if you are new to Angular, this code is too complex to help you easily. You should follow a unit test course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The JavaScript exception "Invalid array length" occurs when specifying an array length that is either negative, a floating number or exceeds the maximum supported by the platform (i.e. when creating an Array or ArrayBuffer, or when setting the length property).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_array_length

I don't know exactly where is `home.component.ts` line 52 char 23 on your image, because you haven't provided code lines, but the trace probably points to this part (just an educated guess):

Observe when variable `nbColumn` in the snippet changes:

```
    this.columns = Array(this.nbColumn - 1)
      .fill(0)
      .map((x, i) => i);
```

`nbColumn = 1`

```js
columns = [];
nbColumn = 1;

this.columns = Array(this.nbColumn - 1).fill(0).map((x, i) => i);

console.log(this.columns)
```

`nbColumn = 0`

```js
columns = [];
nbColumn = 0;

this.columns = Array(this.nbColumn - 1).fill(0).map((x, i) => i);

console.log(this.columns)
```

Probably your test doesn't populate some properties as it does in the actual application. Find out why it is so or fix the likely problematic area `Array(this.nbColumn - 1)`.

Maybe assert that an array is always produced?

```js
this.columns = Array.from(Array(this.nbColumn - 1 > 0 ? this.nbColumn - 1 : 0 ).keys())
```

More on how to use `Array.from()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33352604/15439733