# Alternative code for filling an array with a series incremented by any value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

The following typescript function `seriesIncrementedBy5` returns an array with numbers starting from 5 to `upperLimit` with an increment of 5.

Is there a way to replace this 5 lines of code with any recent typescript ES6 advanced function which will take less than 5 lines.

```
private seriesIncrementedBy5(upperLimit: number): number[] {
    const series = [];
    for (let s = 5; s <= upperLimit + 5; s += 5) {
        series.push(s);
    }
    return series;
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8LVW) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Array.from().... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n

Comment: @wonderflame Yes. That code works. You can move your comment to answer section, and I will choose as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of the correct size and then `map` over it.

```js
const seriesIncrementedBy5 = upperLimit => [...Array((upperLimit/5|0)+1)]
        .map((_, i) => 5 * (i + 1));
console.log(seriesIncrementedBy5(10));
console.log(seriesIncrementedBy5(9));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which can accept an object with the `length: number` property and a second argument populating function:

```
const seriesIncrementedBy5 = (upperLimit: number): number[] =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.floor(upperLimit / 5) + 1 }, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 5);
```

To calculate the length, we divide the `upperLimit` by `5` and floor it to get an integer; it is crucial to add `+ 1` to include the `upperLimit` in the array. To populate, we will use the element's index; since we are starting from `5`, not `0`, we will add `+ 1` to the index and multiply it by `5`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAlvCBJMxHwLbzCngBMAhATwFYYBeGACgFcAHZpAGWV2SgC4YwjXACMkASn6CRSANoBdWgD4AUDBgBBRIgCG5AHQAzRCFz0A3jAA2BAOZQAFvwCy2h4csgQiJqw5ceMAD0MJRiMADUMACMMAC+ADQMAPqJyGE0igzIEdFhAFQhYgDcysqgkCDWeh429AgoaJjYeAREZFT0UQAMYsXKQA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.from` method.

```
private seriesIncrementedBy5(upperLimit: number): number[] {
  return Array.from({ length: Math.floor(upperLimit / 5) }, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 5);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from