# Sort array and return an array of indicies that indicates the position of the sorted elements with respect to the original elements (new)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have this array

```
test = [3, 2, 2, 1];
```

I want to be able to get this array

```
result = [3, 1, 2, 0]
```

The idea is the same as: [Javascript: Sort array and return an array of indicies that indicates the position of the sorted elements with respect to the original elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730510/javascript-sort-array-and-return-an-array-of-indicies-that-indicates-the-positi)

but incrementing the position value every time there is two elements on "test" with the same value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code and explain what didn't work, with a live demo if possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didn't try nothing but the solution proposed by @Dave Aaron Smith on the linked post. From that I get an array: [1,2,2,3]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a comparison function to sort:

```
var test = [3, 2, 2, 1];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i != test.length; ++i) result[i] = i;
result = result.sort(function(u,v) { return test[u] - test[v]; })
console.log(result) // [ 3, 1, 2, 0 ]
```

Comment: just perfect! Well done!

Comment: Well... there is a problem with this solution... http://jsfiddle.net/WQYKd/