# Sort number array and return index js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array. It looks like below:

```
var num = [2,1,2,6,2,4];
```

I would like to sort but return `index` to an array:

```
var result = [1, 0, 2, 4, 5, 3];
```

If there is a same number, the smaller `index` of should be placed first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730510/javascript-sort-array-and-return-an-array-of-indicies-that-indicates-the-positi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all indices and sort with the values of `num`.

```js
var num = [2, 1, 2, 6, 2, 4],
    indices = [...num.keys()].sort((a, b) => num[a] - num[b]);

console.log(indices); // [1, 0, 2, 4, 5, 3]
```