# Array, return original index from a sorted array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

'I wish to sort an array in numerical order but once it is sorted I wish to be able to find the original index.

For example the original array:

`ptsGP = [3,8,2,5,6,9,8,4]`

I am using the following code below to sort the array:

`arr = ptsGP;`

```
var arr2 = arr.map(function(o, i){return {idx: i, obj: o}; }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.obj - a.obj;
});

for(var i = 1, j = arr2.length; i <= j; i++){
    document.write('i:' + i + ' = arr2[i].obj:  PTS: ', arr2[i-1].obj+"<br/>");
}`
```

This is fine as the sorted array is :

`arr = [2,3,4,5,6,8,8,9];`

How can I find the index of sorted number in the original array? In this case it would be :

Index on original array would be  = [2,0,7,3,4,1,6,5]

- I know I could use map on the original array but how can I deal with duplicate numbers i.e, in this case I have two number 8's within the array?

Comment: You can find the original index using `arr2[i-1].idx` due to the `map()` call you did earlier.

Comment: this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730510/javascript-sort-array-and-return-an-array-of-indices-that-indicates-the-positio

Comment: Can you explain the *problem* you have?   Your `arr.map...sort...` returns the exact information you need (albeit you have it in reverse order as it stands)

Comment: Isn't that what `idx` is?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following below steps **:**

- Creating a deep copy of an original array by using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). So that we can get proper indexing.
- Now we can iterate deep copy array to get the index of the elements from an original array.
- Regarding duplicate values we can check via [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) methods.

via  and then via comparison. For fetching the correct index of duplicate values I wrote a logic based on the count of duplicate value.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Original array.
const originalArray = [3, 8, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 4];

// Creating a deep copy of an original array.
const deepCopy = [...originalArray].sort(function(a, b){
    return a-b
});

// result array
const arr = [];

// count to get the index based on duplicate values.
let count = 0;

// Iterating deepCopy array to get the actual index.
deepCopy.forEach((elem) => {
  // Checking for duplicate value in an array
    if (originalArray.indexOf(elem) === originalArray.lastIndexOf(elem)) {
    // This line of code execute if there is no duplicates in an array.
        arr.push(originalArray.indexOf(elem))
  } else {
    // This line of code execute if there is duplicate values in an array. 
        count++;
    // Inserting the index one by one.
    arr.push(originalArray.indexOf(elem, count))
  }
});

// Result array.
console.log(arr);
```