# Sorting an array by their ascending value within the array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

It's a bit of a tricky situation I'm in, but I have an array like this:

```
const nums = [32, -3, 62, 8, 121, -231, 62, 13];
```

and need to replace them by their corresponding ascending index. The above example should yield:

```
[4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 0, 6, 3]
```

The solution I've come up with is this: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbCMC8MDaBmATAGhgFosCA2fGADgIEYcaDCcsGZzasBdAbgChRIsBMgDCIAA4BPNHCQQAdIgCG4gBQBTNAD4Y6gJR9eAMxAAnGKoA262AEsZABm4x7AHlmiJk%20dbABzKAALZ1sAalC9GABvXhg4mBNzKxsYACtHZ3T3YQgxKR91fyDM8MiY%20IqXIwscvMkMW04YbLk6jFTOMtjKnutYWHRar3aebp6KoakRmUn6xr5xytmGpvQoBfGAXzGYbe3jMws%20lwyTls983wDgl1LoneOIMyh1ABMANSVLeE1B1uH5rwdjkMDl5LYwK91AAPADyRlUT1MLw%20Xx%20elWLj4%20wET2sPhAflUOT0QA)

```
const nums = [32, -3, 62, 8, 121, -231, 62, 13];
const numsCopy = nums.map(e => e);

// Basic sorting
for (let i = 0; i < numsCopy.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numsCopy.length; j++) {
        if (numsCopy[i] < numsCopy[j]) {
            let t = numsCopy[j];
            numsCopy[j] = numsCopy[i];
            numsCopy[i] = t;
        }
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < numsCopy.length; i++) {
    let sortedValue = numsCopy[i];

    nums[nums.indexOf(sortedValue)] = i;
}
```

Problems arise however when I change `nums` to include a value `nums.length > n >= 0`. The call `nums.indexOf(...)` may return a faulty result, as it may have already sorted an index, even though it exists somewhere in the array.

If you replace `nums` with these values, `-231` will have an index of `2` for some reason...

```
const nums = [32, -3, 62, 7, 121, -231, 62, 13, 0];

> [5, 1, 6, 3, 8, 2, 7, 4, 0]
```

Is there a better approach to this problem, or a fix to my solution?

Comment: Isn't the answer `5,1,3,7,0,2,6,4` and not `4,1,5,2,7,0,6,3`? Maybe I just don't understand what you mean by "replace them by their corresponding ascending index"

Comment: why do you need to do this? what's the use case? is this homework?

Comment: If you do `nums.sort()`, you get your array sorted in ascending order right? The 1st element will be `-231`, 2nd will be `-3`, etc... And with that data, I'd want to replace their values in `nums` by their respective index in this sorted array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Sort array and return an array of indices that indicates the position of the sorted elements with respect to the original elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730510/javascript-sort-array-and-return-an-array-of-indices-that-indicates-the-positio)

Comment: No, they are very similar though. It's a little hard to explain, but I think I did a better job in the comments of the first answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the indices by the value and create a new array with index values a sorted positions.

to get the wanted result call the sorting function again and you get the indices sorted by the index order.

```js
const
    sort = array => [...array.keys()].sort((a, b) => array[a] - array[b]),
    fn = array => sort(sort(array));

console.log(...fn([32, -3, 62, 8, 121, -231, 62, 13])); // 4 1 5 2 7 0 6 3
console.log(...fn([-1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 9, -2, 7])); // 1 5 3 2 4 7 0 6
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work in some cases. See this TS Playground: https://pastebin.com/zBPGcy1X

Comment: what is wrong`?

Comment: It's a duplicate anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730510/javascript-sort-array-and-return-an-array-of-indices-that-indicates-the-positio/54323161#54323161

Comment: No, it's not the same question. I do not want their index in the array instance, I want it as if they were in ascending order. So if I take the first array you provided in your example: The value `-231` should map, at the same index that `-231` occupied, to 0, as it is the 0th element, in the ascending order, in the list.

Comment: Sorry, this problem is a little unorthodox, but I'm very grateful for the help you've provided :). I hope the above explanation makes things a little clearer....

Comment: @HerbieVine, i have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Well the index of -231 in the original array is 5 right? The new array should also have, at index 5, the value of 0. If the sort the array in ascending order, we get this: [-231, -3, 8, 13, 32, 62, 121]. -231 maps to 0. 121 to 6.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the array, sort its values, get `indexOf`, and `null` the value in the sorted copy:

```js
const sortIndicesByValue = array => {
  const sorted = [...array].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return array.map(e => {
    const i = sorted.indexOf(e);
    sorted[i] = null;
    return i;
  })
}

console.log(...sortIndicesByValue([32, -3, 62, 8, 121, -231, 62, 13]));
console.log(...sortIndicesByValue([-1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 9, -2, 7]));
```