# Sort array items and preserve order of same elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have this array:

```
var array = [
  { name: "border-color", value: "#CCCCCC" },
  { name: "color", value: "#FFFFFF" },
  { name: "background-color", value: "rgb(0, 0, 0)" },
  { name: "background-color", value: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)" }
];
```

And this function to sort the array by name:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

And [ECMAScript language specifications that tell me that](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare
>   equal do not necessarily remain in their original order).

So, after sorting, the two items with name = background color could appear in any order i.e.:

```
[
  { name: "background-color", value: "rgb(0, 0, 0)" },
  { name: "background-color", value: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)" },
  ...
]
```

Or

```
[
  { name: "background-color", value: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)" },
  { name: "background-color", value: "rgb(0, 0, 0)" },
  ...
]
```

How can I sort the array so that items with same name maintain their relative order? I would rather not hardcode anything.

Comment: Check out this answer for short ES6 implementation of stable sort: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660568/1260020

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This changed [as of ES2019](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort), `Array#sort` is **stable**, meaning that the two entries with the same `name` will have the same position relative to one another as they did before the array was sorted:

> **22.1.3.27** Array.prototype.sort ( comparefn )
>
> The elements of this array are sorted. **The sort must be stable** (that is, elements that compare equal must remain in their original order).

*(my emphasis)*

So in your case, the order of `{ name: "background-color", value: "rgb(0, 0, 0)" }` and `{ name: "background-color", value: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)" }` will remain the same, because they compare as equal.

Prior to ES2019, the sort wasn't required to be stable, so they could have had their order reversed — or not, depending on the implementation.

Stable sort is [broadly supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility) (not least because most engines already implemented a stable sort, so there was nothing for them to do).

Comment: Browser support table for stable sorting: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_sort_stable

Answer (score 38):

Theoretically before sorting you could keep track of its index in the array and take that into account when sorting.

```
var sortArray = yourarray.map(function(data, idx){
    return {idx:idx, data:data}
})

sortArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.data.name < b.data.name) return -1;
  if (a.data.name > b.data.name) return 1;
  return a.idx - b.idx
});

var answer = sortArray.map(function(val){
    return val.data
});
```

Comment: where do you get `idx` from?

Comment: Good catch, fixed the name of the arguments on the map function

Comment: @noveyak Since the array contains reference type objet, the index of the element can be determined in the sort function. So we avoid the map before and after the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra attribute to the array: order

```
var array = [
    { name: "border-color", value: "#CCCCCC", order: 1 },
    { name: "color", value: "#FFFFFF", order: 2 },
    { name: "background-color", value: "rgb(0, 0, 0)", order: 3 },
    { name: "background-color", value: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)", order: 4 }
];
```

and then change the sort function to sort on order if the name is equal:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    if (a.name == b.name) {
        if(a.order > b.order) return -1; else return 1;
    }
});
```

Note that the sign of the return for the order has to be tweaked depending on whether you want it sorted increasing or decreasing (here, I assumed you're sorting from largest to smallest, so return the one with the smaller order).

Comment: Using `else` is not needed, after a return statement. You can just do `if(a.order > b.order) return -1; return 1;` . You can also remove the wrapping `if(a.name==b.name){}` statement, which will always be true when executed (because it is neither `>` or `<`).

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, if you cannot guarantee the sort order because of the browser environment or transpiler plugin set-up (in an ideal world, this shouldn't be a problem), a very idiomatic/quick approach could be:

```
values
 .map((v, i) => ([v,i]))
 .sort(([v1,i1], [v2,i2])=> (
     (v1==v2) ? (i2-i1) : (v2-v1)
)).map(([v,i])=>v); // or above flipped
```

The downside of this is it isn't quite as efficient as a merge sort, but it's pretty close since most browser implementations use it for `Array.prototype.sort` internally or even more optimal (and in this case should end up just being about O(2n) + O(nlogn)).

The upside is it's very convenient and easy to read -- imho

Answer (score 0):

Since the array contains reference type objet, the index of the element can be determined in the sort function. So we avoid the map before and after the sort.

```
sortArray.sort((function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  return this.indexOf(a) - this.indexOf(b);
}).bind(sortArray));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow since it has to find the index every time?

Comment: sorry down-voted: this wouldn't be ok because this.indexOf(a) and this.indexOf(b) would change while sorting. You need to memorize the initial indexes before sorting

Comment: Adding with @ionescho, you will also have the wrong index returned by indexOf function, when you have multiple items with the same value in the array.