# How javascript sorts arrays with the same property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the two elements have the same property value on which we sort the array then how javascript order them i mean if you have this array for example :

```
let array = [{id:0,name:"sam",age:"20"},
             {id:0,name:"john",age:"21"},
             {id:1,name:"fred",age:"30"}]
```

let's suppose that i want to sort this array by id ascending then how can i know which one will appear first :

```
{id:0,name:"sam",age:"20"}
```

OR

```
{id:0,name:"john",age:"21"}
```

Comment: depends on how your sorting method is defined. Are you using `.sort()`?

Comment: It depends on the vendors (browser,engine) sorting behavior implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213696/sort-array-items-and-preserve-order-of-same-elements

Comment: you could sort by another property.

Comment: Nick Parsons yes i'm using .sort()

Comment: This is 100% javascript question no reactjs tag is needed

Comment: the newer implementations of `sort` keeps the order for comparisons which return zero.

Comment: why do they share an id?

Answer (score 2):

Up until now the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) was not a [*stable* sort](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort) because there was no mentioning for it in the spec so actually there was no guaranty for a stable (consistent) order.

Though recently, [the spec has changed](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) and the V8 engine [implemented it as a stable sort](https://v8.dev/features/stable-sort).

Comment: It is now. .....

Comment: That's why i wrote _"Though recently, the V8 engine implemented it as a stable sort."_

Comment: It's not just V8. The language specification changed as of ES2019 to **require** a stable sort of implementations. Your first paragraph says it isn't specified. It is.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder! fixed my answer

Answer (score 1):

I realized after answering that this is a duplicate. See [my answer to the dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56891827/157247). Briefly: [As of ES2019](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort), `Array#sort` is **stable**, so in your example "sam" will remain before "john". Prior to ES2019, that wasn't necessarily true, they could have had their order reversed.