# Sort in javascript - ignore sort when same value

Tags: javascript, sorting

If I have an array with objects like this:

```
percentages_oparea
0: 
    name: test1
    pvalue: 15
1: 
    name: test2    
    pvalue: 16
```

I can sort this in javascript this way:

```
percentages_oparea.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(b.pvalue) - parseFloat(a.pvalue);
});
```

and it works correctly:

```
percentages_oparea
0: 
    name: test2
    pvalue: 16
1: 
    name: test1    
    pvalue: 15
```

If `b.value` is exactly the same value `a.value` I don't want to any sorting. how to achieve this?

I don't know why, but I get this result (test1 and test2 switched indexes) when having exactly the same value in pvalue:

```
0: 
    name: test2
    pvalue: 15
1: 
    name: test1    
    pvalue: 15
```

**But I want** (nothing should change)

```
0: 
    name: test1
    pvalue: 15
1: 
    name: test2    
    pvalue: 15
```

Comment: [Sort in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is not a [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sorting algorithm. So it may swap elements of the same value

Comment: Also [Fast stable sorting algorithm implementation in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427608/fast-stable-sorting-algorithm-implementation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring is called *stability* and refers to a sort algorithms capacity to maintain ordering among items that are considered equal.  Not all algorithms can make that guarantee, and unfortunately the algorithm that you're using clearly doesn't.

I recommend you take a look at [this article regarding sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) for a complete list.

Comment: You can update "apparently doesn't" to "definitely doesn't" by reference to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11

Comment: @ChrisLear It wasn't clear whether or not OP was using the standard sort algorithm so I had to leave room for doubt.  ;)