# sort by object value doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var city = [{
"city":"London"
},{
"city":"Wales"
}
,{
"city":"Atom"
}
,{
"city":"Bacelona"
}];

city.sort(function(a,b){
return a.city - b.city;
})

console.log(city)
```

Not sure what's wrong with above code, why it isn't sort? my logic seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return in the function for strings:

```
return a.city.localeCompare(b.city);
```

```js
var city = [{ "city": "London" }, { "city": "Wales" }, { "city": "Atom" }, { "city": "Bacelona" }];

city.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.city.localeCompare(b.city);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(city, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: localCompare versus `>`, which one is better?

Comment: `localeCompare` is slower but easier to use since it outputs -1, 0, and 1 like a sort function should. also also need to be careful not to call it on any non-string properties, or else it will likely throw: `(6).localeCompare("A")`.

Comment: i would go for localeCompare, as my answer suggest. the solution with smaller than is tricky because it returns only two values instead of thee (-1, 0, 1).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `-` operator on strings, they are only for numbers. You need to use `<`, `>`, `<=` or `>=` for lexigraphical order.

Nina Scholz's answer is very useful when you work on non-English words, and it works on English words.

Simply changing the `-` to `>` would make the code work:

```
var city = [{
    "city": "London"
}, {
    "city": "Wales"
}, {
    "city": "Atom"
}, {
    "city": "Bacelona"
}];

city.sort(function(a,b){
    return (a.city > b.city ? 1 : (a.city === b.city ? 0 : -1));
});

console.log(city);
```

Comment: this would be unstable on any duplicated values, in which a `0` should be returned. it's also technically a quirk to not return one of `[-1,0,1]` in a sort(), and it not guaranteed to work everywhere...

Comment: @dandavis, if the city is duplicated, then the order of the two (or more) objects cannot be determined like this. You can include other conditions after this, for example, `return (a.city > b.city) || (a.latitude > b.latitude)`

Comment: nah, you just need something like `return a.city > b.city ? 1 : (a.city==b.city?0:-1);` to avoid shuffling a dupe. objects with duplicate properties and more than one visible prop can simply use the existing index position as a 2nd criterion to achieve stability: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2085225/2317490

Comment: You're right. A number is needed according to the Mozilla documentation