# Array.sort method stops working at Array.length > 10

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, ionic-framework

I am finishing up a hybrid application using Angular on Ionic's framework. I just realized one of my functions is not working.

In my app the user can create a database of items. These items are objects that are stored in items[]. The function in question sorts the objects in this array first by name, then by type, and then by size. The logic in this function works perfectly until more than 10 items have been added to the array.

Here is the items array interface:

```
export interface items {
name: string;
type: string;
size: string;
price: number;
quantity: number;
subTotal: number;
}
```

This is the sorting function:

```
sort() {

this.items = this.items.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.name < b.name){
    return -1;
  }
  if(a.name > b.name){
    return 1;
  }
    return 0;
});

this.items = this.items.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.name == b.name && a.type < b.type){
    return -1;
  }
  if(a.name == b.name && a.type > b.type){
    return 1;
  }
    return 0;
});

this.items = this.items.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.name == b.name && a.type == b.type && a.size < b.size){
    return -1;
  }
  if(a.name == b.name && a.type == b.type && a.size >  b.size){
    return 1;
  }
    return 0;
});
this.storage.set("items", this.items);
}
```

I have narrowed the problem down to being contained in the last part of this sorting function; where it sorts by size:

```
this.items = this.items.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name == b.name && a.type == b.type && a.size < b.size){
      return -1;
    }
    if(a.name == b.name && a.type == b.type && a.size >  b.size){
      return 1;
    }
      return 0;
  });
  this.storage.set("items", this.items);
```

Please let me know why the length of the array is affecting this function and/ or if there is a better way. Thank you so much!

Comment: the size is a number variable? can you please give an example of the array?

Comment: I believe I once read that some browsers switch sorting algorithms based on the length of the list to be sorted. It might be that up until 10 items, it uses a stable sort, which means you can sort by passing a list through several sorting loops consecutively. When the sort is not stable, you can **not** sort by multiple properties by calling `.sort` multiple times. You'll need to define **one** method that does this for you...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a single sort approach with all properties you like to sort with a chained approach, like

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.type.localeCompare(b.type) || a.size - b.size;
});
```

It start with sorting by name and if the name is equal, then it sorts by type, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` uses [different algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44120478/1048572) depending on the array size. And the algorithm for larger arrays is **not stable**, which is why your approach at calling `sort` thrice doesn't work at all. Call `sort` once with a comparison function that does the whole job:

```
sort() {
    this.items.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a.name > b.name) - (a.name < b.name)
            || (a.type > b.type) - (a.type < b.type)
            || (a.size > b.size) - (a.size < b.size);
    });
    this.storage.set("items", this.items);
}
```

Comment: i get  error: "The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type."

Comment: @morganTrudeau Is that typescript? I guess you'll need to put a number cast on each boolean

Answer (score 0):

### A reproduction of the issue

First, let's start by reproducing your problem. Because you haven't given us much to work with, I'll try to construct a "workspace" that gives us some data and clearly visualises results.

What you're essentially doing is chaining three sort methods together:

- Sort by `a` property
- Sort by `b` property if `a` properties match. Otherwise: I don't care, do what you want (return `0`)
- Sort by `c` property if `a` *and* `b` properties match. Otherwise: I don't care, do what you want

Let's make this abstract and define a function that does a (hacky) "sort by property" if a given set of other properties match:

```
// req is an array of properties that are required to be equal
// prop is the property name to sort by
// x and y are objects
const yourSort = (req, prop) 
  => (x, y) 
    => req.every(k => x[k] === y[k]) 
      ? x[prop] - y[prop] 
      : 0;
```

Now, your approach is basically this:

```
const aSort = yourSort([], "a");
const bSort = yourSort(["a"], "b");
const cSort = yourSort(["a", "b"], "c");

const chainedSort = arr =>arr
  .sort(aSort)
  .sort(bSort)
  .sort(cSort)
```

So far, so good. Let's see what happens if we create a list of objects with `a`, `b`, and `c` properties and keep increasing its length:

(note: I've used knockout to render a quick UI, it's not relevant to the actual logic)

```js
const yourSort = (eq, diff) => (x, y) => eq.every(k => x[k] === y[k]) ? x[diff] - y[diff] : 0;

const aSort = yourSort([], "a");
const bSort = yourSort(["a"], "b");
const cSort = yourSort(["a", "b"], "c");

const chainedSort = arr =>arr
  .sort(aSort)
  .sort(bSort)
  .sort(cSort)

// For UI
const length = ko.observable(8);
const sortedItems = ko.pureComputed(
  () => chainedSort(makeItems(Number(length())))
);
ko.applyBindings({ length, sortedItems });

function makeItems(n) { 
  return Array.from(
    Array(n), 
    (_, i) => ({ "a": i % 2, "b": i % 3, "c": Math.random() })
  );
};
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

Number of items: <input type="number" data-bind="textInput: length">

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>  
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: sortedItems">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: a"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: b"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: c"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, in my browser (latest Chrome), you can see everything being messed up for `length > 10`, but in other browsers stuff might even break earlier!

Apparently, the browser switches from a stable sort, in which `return 0` means "leave the initial order of the two items I'm comparing intact", to an unstable sort, in which `return 0` means "you can do whatever you want".

### Solving the issue

The solution to this issue, as posted in my comment and the other answer, is to construct **one** comparison method that takes in to account all properties. You can do this manually, like the other answer proposes, or use a helper function that returns a composed sorter. I chose the latter, but took a shortcut in returning `value1 - value2`, which only really works for number values.

Now, you'll see a correct sort for *any* length.

```js
const sortByProps = props => (obj1, obj2) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i += 1) {
    const k = props[i];
    if (obj1[k] - obj2[k] === 0) continue;
    return obj1[k] - obj2[k];
  }
  
  return 0;  
}

const combinedSort = arr => arr.sort(sortByProps(["a", "b", "c"]));

// For UI
const length = ko.observable(8);
const sortedItems = ko.pureComputed(
  () => combinedSort(makeItems(Number(length())))
);
ko.applyBindings({ length, sortedItems });

function makeItems(n) { 
  return Array.from(
    Array(n), 
    (_, i) => ({ "a": i % 2, "b": i % 3, "c": Math.random() })
  );
};
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

Number of items: <input type="number" data-bind="textInput: length">

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>  
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: sortedItems">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: a"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: b"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: c"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Notice that `return 0` does **not** mean "leave untouched", but rather "I don't care about their ordering, they're equivalent".