# array.prototype.sort present has different order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is my code:

```
let arr = [
  { a: false, index: 1 },
  { a: true, index: 2 },
  { a: false, index: 3 },
  { a: true, index: 4 },
  { a: true, index: 5 },
]

arr.sort((a, b) => a.a && !b.a ? 1 : -1)
```

In Chrome, returns

```
[
  {a: false, index: 1},
  {a: false, index: 3},
  {a: true, index: 2},
  {a: true, index: 4},
  {a: true, index: 5},
]
```

This is my aim result.

But I find same code in Safari:

```
[
  {a: false, index: 3},
  {a: false, index: 1},
  {a: true, index: 5},
  {a: true, index: 4},
  {a: true, index: 2},
]
```

They have different result?

After all, I solve this question by this way:

```
arr.sort(
  (a, b) =>
    !a.a && b.a
      ? -1
      : a.a === b.a
        ? 0
        : 1
)
```

I can't get the diff?

Comment: try this ? `arr.sort((a, b) => a.a === b.a ? a.index > b.index : !b.a)`

Comment: Your first sort function does not meet [the requirements](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort): It claims that objects are not equal to themselves (reflexivity requirement). :"If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), **the sort order is implementation-defined**."

Comment: @RaymondChen Sorry.  I cannot understand your explain a little: what's wrong with my first compare function?

Comment: If `a` is `{ a: false, index: 1 }` and `b` is also `{ a: false, index: 1 }`, the result must be 0 (equal), but instead it returns −1 (less than). One of the rules for sort comparison functions is that objects must be equal to themselves. Your comparison function does not satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers have different implementations of `sort`. Use another sort/filter to organize it more or change your current sort function to account for the index too if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are many sort algorithms and you can define them in two groups:

Stable sort and unstable sort

> A sorting algorithm is said to be stable if two objects with equal
>   keys appear in the same order in the sorted output as they appear in
>   the unsorted input. Whereas a sorting algorithm is said to be unstable
>   if there are two or more objects with equal keys which don't appear in
>   same order before and after sorting.

Since [ECMAScript Array.prototype.sort](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) does not define which algorithm the platform should implement, Safari and Chrome just use different algorithms.

The [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L720) (Chrome) uses insertion sort for small arrays (up to 10 elements) and  quick-sort for larger arrays (which is not stable sort), Safari just uses different sort algorithm(s)

Comment: anyway some advice to avoid this question?

Comment: yes, just implement your own sort algorithm

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1427608/4126633