# Sorting array in javascript by boolean, surname and name

Tags: javascript

I try to sort my array of objects :

object:

```
interface IFriend {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  avatar: string;
  online: boolean;
}
```

I want to do it in order - online, surname, name. I tried this :

```
  friendsCopy
    .sort((a: IFriend, b: IFriend) =>
      a.online === b.online ? 0 : a.online ? -1 : 1
    )
    .sort((a: IFriend, b: IFriend) => a.surname.localeCompare(b.surname, "pl"))
    .sort((a: IFriend, b: IFriend) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, "pl"));
```

But it doesn't work well

Comment: sort function doesn't respect the current order :). this code you write probably only sort's the array by `name` property.

Comment: @HalilCakar say sortin in js is not "stable" you have to use some stable sort algoritms like merge sort [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427608/fast-stable-sorting-algorithm-implementation-in-javascript)

Comment: Well actually it's quite stable for me :D it's just when u sort after sort, the first sort you have made is not relevant to the result =)

Comment: [ES 10 feature - stable sort js](https://buginit.com/javascript/stable-sort-array-javascript-es10/) so is stable in chorme :P (now)

Comment: Please be aware this type of sorting requires stable sort, most modern browsers do support it,  but of course IE11 doesn't...  https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_sort_stable   It is possible to do this with one sort, if maximum browser compatibly is required.  Or maybe a pollyfill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are sorting in the wrong direction.

If you reverse the functions then it should give your desired output:

```
friendsCopy
    .sort((a: IFriend, b: IFriend) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, "pl"))
    .sort((a: IFriend, b: IFriend) => a.surname.localeCompare(b.surname, "pl"))
    .sort((a: IFriend, b: IFriend) =>
      a.online === b.online ? 0 : a.online ? -1 : 1
    );
```

Sort by name, then sort by surnames, then sort by who is online.
The final list will be online -> surname -> name

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, you are sorting in the reverse direction. The final `sort` is prioritized over the others.

You can club them all to a single `sort` using the `||` operator.

```
friendsCopy.sort((a, b) => b.online - a.online 
                || a.surname.localeCompare(b.surname, "pl") 
                || a.name.localeCompare(b.name, "pl")
    )
```

First, sort the array by `online` property. You can simply subtract the booleans since they get coerced to numbers and result in -1, 0 or 1 based on their value.

```
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
true - true === 0
false - false === 0
```

All the `online: true` objects will be moved to the front of the array. If both the objects being compared have the same `online` value, then the subtraction returns `0` and the `||` operator moves to the next condition and sorts them based on `surname`. Again, if the objects have the same `surname` property, then finally the objects are sorted based on `name` property.

Comment: Most Modern JS engines use stable sort, so the previous sort is not messed up, it's just the OP has sorted by name, surname, online instead.   But personally I would use a single sort anyway.   IOW: Why do 3 sorts when 1 will do.  So I'm up-voting this one.

Comment: @Keith maybe *messed up* is not the correct word. If the compare function returns  `0`, they will keep their relative positions. But, the newer sort will ignore the previous `sort` if it returns -1 or 1