# javascript sort ambiguity on different browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, browser, cross-browser

I got rather fairly standard JS array, similar to this:

```
"entities": [
    {
      "id": "1111",
      "options": {
        "label": "Label",
        "choices": [
          {
            "value": "222222"
          },
          {
            "value": "444444"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2222",
      "options": {
        "label": "Label",
        "choices": [
          {
            "value": "333333"
          },
          {
            "value": "555555"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
...
```

I got sorting function that always tells that two elements are equal, that looks like that:

```
function sortF(a,b){
    return 0;
}
```

Now I sort entities array like:

```
entities.sort(sortF);
```

No change is my expected behavior here, but results are different on different browsers. For example on IE it is fine, but on Chrome it sorts the array in different order.

On MDN I noticed this under sort description, but not sure if this is relevant:

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with
>   respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>   elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>   behaviour

How can I make this to work the same in all browsers? I want sort function to leave the order as it was if my sort function says that two elements are equal.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you need to clone arrays use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice; if "sorting" is really the best way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195941/sorting-an-array-of-objects-in-chrome/3195977#3195977.

Comment: In practice my sortF function is more complex, but I reduced it just to return 0 and I still have this problem

Comment: *The sort is not necessarily stable.* from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: i suggest to include a property with the index of the original sort order.

Comment: It sounds like you essentially want the `noop` version of a `sort` parameter.

Comment: Provided that you give the same function all browsers should end up the same result even if their sorting algorithm differ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to make a stable sort with an own property for sorting:

```
entities.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.origin = i;
});


function sortF(a, b){
    return a.origin - b.origin;
}

entities.sort(sortF);
```

Result, a stable sort with the same sort order as the original array