# Why does this incorrect sorting (a comparator that returns boolean) work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting, firefox

**I understand that this behaviour is due to return 0 in the comparator, my question is about why this wrong code still worked in Firefox. Please read the whole question before answering.**

I have this set of data:

```
var data = [
  'Salas Mccarthy',
  'Jodi Graham',
  'Hollie Hardin',
  'Bullock Cole',
  'Peterson Mosley',
  'Lucille Jackson',
  'Cooper Leonard',
  'Iris Shepherd',
  'Oneil Head',
  'Swanson Singleton',
  'Sutton Odom'
]

console.log(data.sort(function (a, b) { return a > b; }));
```

Running that code in Chrome browser gives me a non-sorted result:

```
["Lucille Jackson", "Salas Mccarthy", "Hollie Hardin", "Bullock Cole", "Peterson Mosley", "Jodi Graham", "Cooper Leonard", "Iris Shepherd", "Oneil Head", "Sutton Odom", "Swanson Singleton"]
```

while running that same code in Firefox gives me a sorted result:

```
[ "Bullock Cole", "Cooper Leonard", "Hollie Hardin", "Iris Shepherd", "Jodi Graham", "Lucille Jackson", "Oneil Head", "Peterson Mosley", "Salas Mccarthy", "Sutton Odom", "Swanson Singleton"]
```

My understanding is that if I returned `a > b` like I did, `true/false` gets converted to `1/0` and `0` means leave it unchanged with respect to each other. Hence I understand that Chrome gives me a non-sorted result with the incorrect comparator.

I should have returned a numeric value in the comparator function, such as

```
data.sort(function (a, b) { return a > b ? 1 : -1; })
```

Doing so will give consistent sorted results in both browsers. But I'm still puzzled why it works in Firefox in the first place?

Afterwards, I removed `Salas Mccarthy` from the array. Both Chrome and Firefox sorts the array nicely even with the incorrect comparator!

```
var data = [
  'Jodi Graham',
  'Hollie Hardin',
  'Bullock Cole',
  'Peterson Mosley',
  'Lucille Jackson',
  'Cooper Leonard',
  'Iris Shepherd',
  'Oneil Head',
  'Swanson Singleton',
  'Sutton Odom'
]

console.log(data.sort(function (a, b) { return a > b }));
```

Results for both Chrome and Firefox:

```
["Bullock Cole", "Cooper Leonard", "Hollie Hardin", "Iris Shepherd", "Jodi Graham", "Lucille Jackson", "Oneil Head", "Peterson Mosley", "Sutton Odom", "Swanson Singleton"]
```

These sorting behaviours are really really odd, can anyone explain it?

Comment: Yes I have realized that mistake (as stated in the question). So my question is that why does it work in Firefox in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't work in FF either. You might get correct order, but that depends on the original order. Other implementations might "refuse" to sort, if incorrect values are passed.

Comment: because their sorting algo is different ? They probably don't take all the items in the same order in the first place, thus final results when you never output -1 will be different

Comment: @Teemu any source on this latter affirmation ? Does this mean that `sort((a,b) => a - b)` may fail ?

Comment: @kaiido It's rather an assumption ("might") than an affirmation. It's also possible, that FF ignores the custom sort function when it returns illegal values, and falls back to basic sorting ..?

Comment: See the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort), there are several cases when "_the sort order is implementation-defined_". In your case "_... comparefn is not ... a consistent comparison function ..._"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of objects in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195941/sorting-an-array-of-objects-in-chrome) but for what it's worse, I read they do implement quick sort for less than 10 items)

Comment: @Teemu Not sure if that's the case. I had a custom sorting function to sort hour strings in the `HH:MM:ss` format (that was returning booleans instead of integers). It worked perfectly in Firefox (57) though, but it wouldn't if it forced a fallback to the default sorting function.

Comment: It just can't work perfectly in any implementation, even if the booleans would be converted to integers (0 or 1) internally, the -1 case never occurs, and the sorting goes to haywire. It might work occasionally, if the data is already in such order, that -1 (or negative, if that matters) case is not needed, or, the implementation ignores the custom sorting function altogether, if it returns something else than integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [].sort() without callback-function on an array of strings, if all you want is a lexigraph sorting: sort() is first and foremost a unicode lexigraph sort function, if not used with a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**localeCompare**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method to returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order

```js
var data = [
  'Salas Mccarthy',
  'Jodi Graham',
  'Hollie Hardin',
  'Bullock Cole',
  'Peterson Mosley',
  'Lucille Jackson',
  'Cooper Leonard',
  'Iris Shepherd',
  'Oneil Head',
  'Swanson Singleton',
  'Sutton Odom'
]

console.log(data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b);
}));
```

Comment: Question is *Why* is it working in FF and why not in chrome.