# Sort undefined value in javascript works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting

I have an array of object like:

```
var arr = [{index: 1, key: undefined}, {index: 2, key: undefined},{index: 3, key: undefined},{index: 4, key: undefined},{index: 5, key: undefined},{index: 6, key: undefined},{index: 7, key: undefined},{index: 8, key: undefined},{index: 9, key: undefined},{index: 10, key: undefined},{index: 11, key: undefined},{index: 12, key: undefined},{index: 13, key: undefined},{index: 14, key: undefined},{index: 15, key: undefined},{index: 16, key: undefined},{index: 17, key: undefined},{index: 18, key: undefined},{index: 19, key: undefined} ]
```

I want to sort array arr by key - here is all undefined value. The return value should be the same as arr. But when i execute:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.key - b.key})
```

The result is not the same as i expected, the array order is changed. Any idea on this problem?

My result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksCQ5.jpg

Update: Tested with another array:

```
var b = [{index: 1, key: 10}, {index: 2, key: 10},{index: 3, key: 10},{index: 4, key: 10},{index: 5, key: 10},{index: 6, key: 10},{index: 7, key: 10},{index: 8, key: 10},{index: 9, key: 10},{index: 10, key: 10},{index: 11, key: 10},{index: 12, key: 10},{index: 13, key: 10},{index: 14, key: 10},{index: 15, key: 10},{index: 16, key: 10},{index: 17, key: 10},{index: 18, key: 10},{index: 19, key: 10} ]
```

Every key has same value, but when sort function is call: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usar5.jpg

IE and Firefox is work OK, the problem happens in Chrome.
I guess something go wrong with the case return 0.

Comment: Looks the same on my end

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4NyDq

Here is my result

Comment: @Eddie Please try in chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of objects in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195941/sorting-an-array-of-objects-in-chrome)

Comment: @vicnoob: can you select an answer for this question? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related with the stability of algorithms used inside `array.sort` implementation which depends on the engine used to execute your javascript code.

Chrome uses [Google’s V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/). 
V8's sort algorithm use a combination of *insertion-sort* and *quick-sort*. Check the actual implementation [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L761).

*Insertion-sort* is used when the array is small (`array.length <= 10`), otherwise *quick-sort* is used. The second sorting algorithm is unstable, and don't provide any guarantee about preserving order of equivalent elements.

As conclusion, I include two tests (both using your initial comparison function). Chrome's results:

- the first sort is performed on 10 elements array (therefore, original order is preserved)
- the second sort is performed on your original array with 19 elements (in this case there is no certainty about keeping original order, and that's why the array order is changed)

```js
const small = [
  {index: 1, key: undefined}, 
  {index: 2, key: undefined},
  {index: 3, key: undefined},
  {index: 4, key: undefined},
  {index: 5, key: undefined},
  {index: 6, key: undefined},
  {index: 7, key: undefined},
  {index: 8, key: undefined},
  {index: 9, key: undefined},
  {index: 10, key: undefined}
];

// stable sort
small.sort(function(a,b){return a.key - b.key});
console.log(small);

var arr = [
  ...small,
  {index: 11, key: undefined},
  {index: 12, key: undefined},
  {index: 13, key: undefined},
  {index: 14, key: undefined},
  {index: 15, key: undefined},
  {index: 16, key: undefined},
  {index: 17, key: undefined},
  {index: 18, key: undefined},
  {index: 19, key: undefined}
];

// unstable sort
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.key - b.key});
console.log(arr);
```

Probably you need to implement a stable sorting algorithm to ensure your code will behave the same despite the environment in which will be executed.
The most common stable algorithms are [bubble-sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/), [insertion-sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/) and [merge-sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/).

Read more about [stability in sorting algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stability-in-sorting-algorithms/)

Check chromium bug: [V8 doesn't stable sort](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=90)

[Javascript engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines). [More](https://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-guide-to-javascript-engines-for-idiots/).

Comment: not really, the problem is a shitty implementation of the `sort` method in `Google Chrome` browser

Comment: Checkout the second case of my question ( i just updated). Actually i have custom function to define that if both a,b are undefined or null, the callback function will return 0, but the order is still wrong, so I guess that the problem is not the result is NaN or 0, but Chrome has some problem with the case return 0 of sort function. FF and IE worked

Comment: Ok. The problem is with the `.sort` algorithm stability which depends of the engine implementation... I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Do the following....

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return (!a || !b)? 0 : (a.key - b.key) })
```

Comment: It still not work, you can try on Chrome. And the problem is the same with the array like

    var b = [{index: 1, key: 10}, {index: 2, key: 10},{index: 3, key: 10},{index: 4, key: 10},{index: 5, key: 10},{index: 6, key: 10},{index: 7, key: 10},{index: 8, key: 10},{index: 9, key: 10},{index: 10, key: 10},{index: 11, key: 10},{index: 12, key: 10},{index: 13, key: 10},{index: 14, key: 10},{index: 15, key: 10},{index: 16, key: 10},{index: 17, key: 10},{index: 18, key: 10},{index: 19, key: 10} ]

I guess that something happens with return 0 case

Comment: yes. the problem is the algorithm used to sort elements on chrome which use a non stable sorting for large arrays. check my answer above..

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to subtract `undefined` from `undefined`, and the result is `NaN`.

```
NaN < 0
> false

NaN > 0
> false
```

`NaN` is not `-1` neither is `1`, and it is not greater nor lesser than 0, so it seems to be treated as `0`.

I'm not sure if the above sentence is true.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description):

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. **Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.**

So I've tested this in `Firefox` and the order stay unchanged. But doing the same in `Chrome` reproduced your problem.

Comment: Thanks, i tested with Ff and it worked. I also tested with an array object that every key is equal each other. The problem still the same, do you have any idea on fixing this?

Comment: what i expect is it treated as 0, if it treated as zero then the order should not be changed, am i right?. Tested with the array var b = [{index: 1, key: 10}, {index: 2, key: 10},{index: 3, key: 10},{index: 4, key: 10},{index: 5, key: 10},{index: 6, key: 10},{index: 7, key: 10},{index: 8, key: 10},{index: 9, key: 10},{index: 10, key: 10},{index: 11, key: 10},{index: 12, key: 10},{index: 13, key: 10},{index: 14, key: 10},{index: 15, key: 10},{index: 16, key: 10},{index: 17, key: 10},{index: 18, key: 10},{index: 19, key: 10} ] in Chrome, the problem happens again

Comment: @ago @vicnoob according to MDN (again) it happens only for `0`s (and your comparator returned some-kind-of-zero for both of the arrays), so maybe try to use some external library for sorting your array, I bet you are not the first one who encountered this problem

Comment: I can't use another library, but thank for your advise, I'm trying to find the way to solve it

Comment: Oh that's a good idea. But in my real problem, i can not know what column has every value is the same or undefined. My data is fetched from API. If I know that all the value of the column is undefined, I can simply ignore the sort function and return the old array. I'm asking this question to be sure that there is no problem with the sort function, but somehow there is a problem :'(