# Is this a bug in Array.sort()?

Tags: javascript, sorting

It's hard to believe, but this looks like a bug in Google Chrome's Javascript engine.  Am I missing something?

Chrome Javascript console session:

```
> x = [10, 1]
> x.sort()
[1, 10]
> // OK.  But now try this.
> x = [10, 2]
> x.sort()
[10, 2]
```

It didn't sort it!

I'm currently running Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: Strange. I've tested it in FF and Opera - same result.

Comment: Many thanks to the people who took the time to answer.  In hindsight, it's "obvious" what's going on.  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort not working with integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/sort-not-working-with-integers)

Comment: this is the elephant in the room.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`array.sort()` sorts the array in lexicographical order. That means, the values of the array are interpreted as Strings and sorted like Strings (alphabetically), not like integers.

This behavior is also described here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

Comment: Thanks.  That explains it.

Answer (score 7):

For those who came here figuring out what the heck is wrong with sorting in Chrome, here's an example of what `unstable sort` is: https://jsfiddle.net/wujpw8bo/

How to fix it:

> Unstable sorting algorithms can be specially implemented to be stable. One way of doing this is to artificially extend the key comparison, so that comparisons between two objects with otherwise equal keys are decided using the order of the entries in the original input list as a tie-breaker. Remembering this order, however, may require additional time and space.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with the question from the opener - but I learned something today. Thanks man! Upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I think MDN has Explained it well [Source MDN Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>   is according to string **Unicode code points**.

```
arr.sort([compareFunction])
```

> **compareFunction** *Optional*
>
> 1. Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the
>      array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.
> 2. If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting
>      them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order. For
>      example, "*Cherry*" comes before "*banana*". In a numeric sort, 9 comes
>      before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes
>      before "9" in Unicode order.

```
var scores = [1, 10, 2, 21]; 
scores.sort(); // [1, 10, 2, 21]
// Watch out that 10 comes before 2,
// because '10' comes before '2' in Unicode code point order.
```

> To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply
>   subtract b from a. The following function will sort the array
>   ascending:

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Example:

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
var scores = ['1', '010', '200', '110']; 
scores.sort(compareNumbers);
```

> **O/P:** Array [ "1", "010", "110", "200" ]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following method:

```
abc =[10,2,4,1]; abc.sort(function( a , b ){
  return a-b;
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score -1):

You're missing brackets on your second **[sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```
x.sort()
```

**Edit:**
Just tried it myself and even with brackets its not working.

Check these questions out. Maybe they'll fix your problem.

[Sorting an array of objects in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195941/sorting-an-array-of-objects-in-chrome)

[Sorting Javascript Array with Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969145/sorting-javascript-array-with-chrome)

**Edit2:**
This works as expected:

```
var x;
x = [10, 2]; 
alert(x); // returns 10, 2
x.sort ( function( a , b ){
  return a-b;
});
alert(x); // returns 2,10
```

Comment: This is just a typo, and not related to the question.