# Simple function to sort an array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I would like to create a (non-anonymous) function that sorts an array of objects alphabetically by the key `name`. I only code straight-out JavaScript so frameworks don't help me in the least.

```
var people = [
    {'name': 'a75', 'item1': false, 'item2': false},
    {'name': 'z32', 'item1': true,  'item2': false},
    {'name': 'e77', 'item1': false, 'item2': false}
];
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Why do you explicitly want a non-anonymous function?

Comment: A non-anonymous function sorting(json_object,key_to_sort_by) {}

Comment: Added the quotes, haven't coded for a few days! Just want to figure out how JSON and JavaScript set the key and then sort. Figure if it's not integer based I could use the sort method perhaps?

Comment: Anonymous function example: window.onload = function() {/* stuff();*/}

Comment: You want a function to sort the array, then?

Comment: What you list above is not JSON, it is a plain JavaScript object. JSON is the string encoded version of a JavaScript object.

Comment: Sorting an object (array-like since JavaScript calls it an object) essentially as far as I see it only tagging it as JSON...not sure if there is any special JSON - specific code. If I call out the names then I want, 'a75','e77','z32' when sorting by name.

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/json-sorting-question)

Comment: Okay, I keep seeing a, b and it's not processing in my head. Is that a loop of some sort that I'm not figuring? I'm not sure how to *call* that and that's an anonymous function, I want a normal function I can recall and work on please.

Comment: @John A sort function takes 2 arguments (such as a,b) because you are comparing 2 different items each time, until sorting is completed.  A sort function returns 1 if the 'a' should be after the 'b' argument, -1 if it should be before, or 0 if they are equivalent

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: I took the liberty of removing mentions to JSON because it's really not about JSON and it's a good reference question.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I asked this question in 2011 and the question *you* referenced was asked 11 hours ago. Stop wasting people's time.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

How about this?

```
var people = [
{
    name: 'a75',
    item1: false,
    item2: false
},
{
    name: 'z32',
    item1: true,
    item2: false
},
{
    name: 'e77',
    item1: false,
    item2: false
}];

function sort_by_key(array, key)
{
 return array.sort(function(a, b)
 {
  var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
  return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
 });
}

people = sort_by_key(people, 'name');
```

This allows you to specify the key by which you want to sort the array so that you are not limited to a hard-coded name sort. It will work to sort any array of objects that all share the property which is used as they key. I believe that is what you were looking for?

And here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Dgbu/

Comment: Is it possible to sort by 2 keys? eg. 'last_name', 'first_name'? (similar to mysql's ORDER BY field). Thanks!

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker - I really like the solution in this answer -- what if I wanted to sort by MULTIPLE keys?  Is that possible with this solution or better handled another way?

Comment: for Descending order of sorting , what should be done ?

Comment: It doesn't work with upper/lowercase values. Please update the code with `var x = a[key].toLowerCase(); var y = b[key].toLowerCase();`

Comment: This algorithm messes up stacksort. Please fix

Comment: Hello from StackSort ! Nice answer, did the job.

Comment: And to change the sort order, do this:     return array.sort(function(b,a)

Answer (score 32):

You can sort an *array* (`[...]`) with the `.sort` function:

```
var people = [
    {'name': 'a75', 'item1': false, 'item2': false},
    {'name': 'z32', 'item1': true,  'item2': false},
    {'name': 'e77', 'item1': false, 'item2': false},
];

var sorted = people.sort(function IHaveAName(a, b) { // non-anonymous as you ordered...
    return b.name < a.name ?  1 // if b should come earlier, push a to end
         : b.name > a.name ? -1 // if b should come later, push a to begin
         : 0;                   // a and b are equal
});
```

Comment: Thanks though that is an annoymous function, I'm trying to do function sort_example(object_name,key_to_sort_by) {}

Comment: @John: It's a named function expression now :) What you want is not too difficult, have a try.

Comment: so after sort what should i console, sorted or people

Answer (score 9):

This isn't a JSON question, per se. Its a javascript array question.

Try this:

```
people.sort(function(a,b){ 
    var x = a.name < b.name? -1:1; 
    return x; 
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to do function sort_example(object_name,key_to_sort_by) {}

Comment: +1 I used this to sort prices and I just inverted the bracket '<' for '>' and I got the prices sorted from lowest to highest. Thank you!

Comment: This can blow badly because of comparing same elements returning `1`. Depending on the sort function user, anything can happen.

Answer (score 5):

I modified @Geuis 's answer by using lambda and convert it upper case first:

```
people.sort((a, b) => a.toLocaleUpperCase() < b.toLocaleUpperCase() ? -1 : 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution for similar sort problem using ECMA 6

```js
var library = [
        {name: 'Steve', course:'WAP', courseID: 'cs452'}, 
        {name: 'Rakesh', course:'WAA', courseID: 'cs545'},
        {name: 'Asad', course:'SWE', courseID: 'cs542'},
];

const sorted_by_name = library.sort( (a,b) => a.name > b.name );

for(let k in sorted_by_name){
    console.log(sorted_by_name[k]);
}
```

Comment: Interesting though subjective to browser share / compatibility. If it will work in IE11 then 2017 compatibility is fair otherwise if it requires IE12 ("Edge") it will have to wait until circa 2020. Looks slightly less verbal...though when I originally posted this I asked for a non-anonymous function I could call.

Comment: Are you sure this is meant to work according to standards? `<` on strings returns just `true` or `false` on Node v14.17.0, not the desired -1, 0, 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.sort_by = function(key_func, reverse=false){
    return this.sort( (a, b) => ( key_func(b) - key_func(a) ) * (reverse ? 1 : -1) ) 
}
```

Then for example if we have

```
var arr = [ {id: 0, balls: {red: 8,  blue: 10}},
            {id: 2, balls: {red: 6 , blue: 11}},
            {id: 1, balls: {red: 4 , blue: 15}} ]
```

```
arr.sort_by(el => el.id, reverse=true)
/* would result in
[ { id: 2, balls: {red: 6 , blue: 11 }},
  { id: 1, balls: {red: 4 , blue: 15 }},
  { id: 0, balls: {red: 8 , blue: 10 }} ]
*/
```

or

```
arr.sort_by(el => el.balls.red + el.balls.blue)
/* would result in
[ { id: 2, balls: {red: 6 , blue: 11 }},    // red + blue= 17
  { id: 0, balls: {red: 8 , blue: 10 }},    // red + blue= 18
  { id: 1, balls: {red: 4 , blue: 15 }} ]   // red + blue= 19
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

`var data = [ 1, 2, 5, 3, 1];
data.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b });`

With a small compartor and using sort, we can do it

Answer (score 0):

This is how simply I sort from previous examples:

if my array is `items`:

```
0: {id: 14, auctionID: 76, userID: 1, amount: 39}
1: {id: 1086, auctionID: 76, userID: 1, amount: 55}
2: {id: 1087, auctionID: 76, userID: 1, amount: 55}
```

I thought simply calling `items.sort()` would sort it it, but there was two problems:
1. Was sorting them strings
2. Was sorting them first key

This is how I modified the sort function:

```
for(amount in items){
if(item.hasOwnProperty(amount)){

i.sort((a, b) => a.amount - b.amount);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting alphabetically with lambda function:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var library = [
        {name: 'Steve', course:'WAP', courseID: 'cs452'}, 
        {name: 'Rakesh', course:'WAA', courseID: 'cs545'},
        {name: 'Asad', course:'SWE', courseID: 'cs542'},
];

const sorted_by_name = library.sort( (a,b) => a.name > b.name );

for(let k in sorted_by_name){
    console.log(sorted_by_name[k]);
}
```

Comment: It is always nice to put some explanatory text along with your code, when answering questions.

Comment: The compare function returns a boolean, it should return a number

Answer (score -1):

```js
var library = [
        {name: 'Steve', course:'WAP', courseID: 'cs452'}, 
        {name: 'Rakesh', course:'WAA', courseID: 'cs545'},
        {name: 'Asad', course:'SWE', courseID: 'cs542'},
];

const sorted_by_name = library.sort( (a,b) => a.name > b.name ? 1:-1 );

for(let k in sorted_by_name){
    console.log(sorted_by_name[k]);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
var people = 
[{"name": 'a75',"item1": "false","item2":"false"}, 
{"name": 'z32',"item1": "true","item2":  "false"}, 
{"name": 'e77',"item1": "false","item2": "false"}]; 

function mycomparator(a,b) {   return parseInt(a.name) - parseInt(b.name);  } 
people.sort(mycomparator);
```

something along the lines of this maybe (or as we used to say, this should work).

Comment: `parseInt('a75')` is `NaN` so this won't really work I guess.

Comment: I don;t think this is appropriate solution when we are dealing with string value, because parseInt on string might give unexpected value, but yaa if you are comparing a string having numeric or decimal value then it will work