# Sorting simple JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Since I've noticed the browser can't guarantee the ordering of a JSON trough an ajax call ([reference](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1107)), I'm having some troubles with sorting the JSON element with javascript after the ajax call.

I've found some topics about this issue, but nothing gave me a clear solution for the simple structure of my JSON object. I just got 1 segment with a lot of data.
I know there are a lot of topics about this, even on stackoverflow, but no topic handles this simple json structure.

For example:

```
{
   "158":"Banana",
   "265":"Pear",
   "358":"Apple",
   "864":"Peach"
}
```

How can I sort this object on the fruitnames instead of the id's?
I'd like to have this object at the end:

```
{
   "358":"Apple",
   "158":"Banana",
   "864":"Peach"
   "265":"Pear",
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-a-json-object-using-javascript

Comment: underscore.js has a nice `sortBy()` function: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy

Comment: Objects aren't in any particular order.  If you want them in order, use an array (of objects) instead.

Comment: That is not a JSON object. JSON is a string notation. You ***parse*** the JSON string ***into*** an ***object literal***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var kk = {
   "158":"Banana",
   "265":"Pear",
   "358":"Apple",
   "864":"Peach"
}

var keys = [];
var datas = {}

$.each(kk, function(key, value){

  keys.push(value)
  datas[value] = key;

})
    var aa = keys.sort()

        var sorted ={}

$.each(aa, function(index, value){

    sorted[datas[value]] = value;
})
```

Comment: It's just the other way around. I want to sort on the names not on the id's, but I'm trying a solution with your code example.

Comment: The for each you use to create the sorted object, can be used to solve a problem. But keep this in mind **'Objects aren't in any particular order. If you want them in order, use an array (of objects) instead'**.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var someObject = {
   "158":"Banana",
   "265":"Pear",
   "358":"Apple",
   "864":"Peach"
};

//flip the name/value pairs
Object.prototype["reverseObject"] = function() {
    var name;
    var newObject = {};
    for(name in this) {
        if(typeof this[name] !== 'function') {
           newObject[this[name]] = name;
        }
    }
    return newObject;
}

var reversedObject = someObject.reverseObject();

console.log(reversedObject);

var i;
var properties = [];
//get all the property names
$.each(reversedObject, function(key, value) {
    if(reversedObject[key] !== this)
    properties.push(key);
});

properties.sort();

var sortedObject = [];

//iterate the array using the order specified
for(i = 0; i < properties.length; i += 1) {
    sortedObject[properties[i]] = reversedObject[properties[i]];
    //document.writeln(properties[i] + " : " + reversedObject[properties[i]]);
}

var sortedObject = sortedObject.reverseObject();

console.log(sortedObject);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/4bwBb/14/)

This creates a sorted array of property names in alphabetical order.  Then, this array is used to index the object.  This results in the exact object you requested.