# Sort array of objects by single key with date value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with several key value pairs, and I need to sort them based on 'updated_at':

```
[
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
]
```

What's the most efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Here's an example:

```js
var arr = [{
    "updated_at": "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var keyA = new Date(a.updated_at),
    keyB = new Date(b.updated_at);
  // Compare the 2 dates
  if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `keyA - keyB` (or possibly `keyB - keyA`)? The date objects have a `valueOf()` method.

Comment: If you want to sort based on numeric values from your keys then this ES6 one-liner might be of help. `yourArr.sort((a, b) => a.yourNumericOrderingKey > b.yourNumericOrderingKey)`. In my case I had to sort based on an `order` key that was coming inside the objects of main array.

Comment: Not working in Chrome Mobile version >= 88.0.4324.152

Comment: Not really any need to convert to date objects because with ISO format alphabetical and chronological order are the same. So you can just sort as strings. As long as all values are in proper ISO format (including being in UTC)

Comment: In 2012 this was a fine answer. In 2021, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value/70319634?noredirect=1#comment124367399_70319634

Answer (score 202):

I already answered a really similar question here: [Simple function to sort an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-a-json-object-using-javascript/8175221#8175221)

For that question I created this little function that might do what you want:

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

Comment: Not working in Chrome Mobile version >= 88.0.4324.152

Answer (score 68):

The [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. Be careful with [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as it's not [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/). For immutable sort use [immutable-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable-sort).

This method is to sort the array using your current `updated_at` in ISO format. We use `new Data(iso_string).getTime()` to convert ISO time to Unix timestamp. A Unix timestamp is a number that we can do simple math on. We subtract the first and second timestamp the result is; if the first timestamp is bigger than the second the return number will be positive. If the second number is bigger than the first the return value will be negative. If the two are the same the return will be zero. This alines perfectly with the required return values for the inline function.

For [ES6](http://es6-features.org/):

```
arr.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.updated_at).getTime() - new Date(b.updated_at).getTime());
```

For [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){ 
 return new Date(a.updated_at).getTime() - new Date(b.updated_at).getTime();
});
```

If you change your `updated_at` to be unix timestamps you can do this:

For [ES6](http://es6-features.org/):

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a.updated_at - b.updated_at);
```

For [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){ 
 return a.updated_at - b.updated_at;
});
```

At the time of this post, modern browsers do not support ES6. To use ES6 in modern browsers use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the code to ES5. Expect browser support for ES6 in the near future.

[Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should receave a return value of one of 3 possible outcomes:

- A positive number (first item > second item)
- A negative number (first item < second item)
- 0 if the two items are equal

> Note that the return value on the inline function can be any
>   positive or negative number. Array.Sort() does not care what the
>   return number is. It only cares if the return value is positive,
>   negative or zero.

For Immutable sort: (example in ES6)

```
const sort = require('immutable-sort');
const array = [1, 5, 2, 4, 3];
const sortedArray = sort(array);
```

You can also write it this way:

```
import sort from 'immutable-sort';
const array = [1, 5, 2, 4, 3];
const sortedArray = sort(array);
```

The import-from you see is a new way to include javascript in ES6 and makes your code look very clean. My personal favorite.

Immutable sort doesn't mutate the source array rather it returns a new array. Using `const` is recommended on immutable data.

Comment: Another immutable alternative would be to use arr.slice().sort(...)

Comment: Not working in Chrome Mobile version >= 88.0.4324.152

Comment: as stated, you must use a transpiler like babel for ES6. You CAN NOT use ES6 in native browsers without a transpiler.

Answer (score 25):

Use underscore js or lodash,

```
var arrObj = [
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
];

arrObj = _.sortBy(arrObj,"updated_at");
```

`_.sortBy()` returns a new array

refer http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy and
lodash docs https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Answer (score 23):

With ES2015 support it can be done by:

```
foo.sort((a, b) => a.updated_at < b.updated_at ? -1 : 1)
```

Comment: no need for the inline if replace the < with - and remove '? -1 : 1"  you will get a valid return. This example moves items that may be equal and so could give unexpected results. for equal items a 0 should be returned.

Comment: if updated_at is an ISO time this will not work. This example assumes Unix timestamps but the OP posted data that was in ISO format. So you would have to convert to Unix timestamps to do a comparison. This can be done with `new Date(iso_str).getTime()` this will return a Unix timestamp.

Comment: This worked perfectly when sorting my array of objects based on a string value. I tried just using< like Patrick mentioned and it didn't sort my array correctly. Nice work.

Answer (score 21):

Here's a slightly modified version of [@David Brainer-Bankers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837505/26510) that sorts alphabetically by string, or numerically by number, and ensures that words beginning with Capital letters don't sort above words starting with a lower case letter (e.g  "apple,Early" would be displayed in that order).

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key];
        var y = b[key];

        if (typeof x == "string")
        {
            x = (""+x).toLowerCase(); 
        }
        if (typeof y == "string")
        {
            y = (""+y).toLowerCase();
        }

        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution might give an error if a[key] and b[key] are not both strings. I suggest to replace y=y.toLowerCase() with y = (""+y).toLowerCase()

Comment: sort can accept any positive or negative number as a valid return. You're extra calculations to force it to be 1,0,-1 is not needed. You over complicated a simple return value. It's best to not add extra calculations that don't do anything.

Answer (score 10):

I'm getting here a little late, but in 2021 the correct answer is to use [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator). `updated_at` is an ISO-8601 string and thus sortable as a string. Converting to a `Date` is a waste of time and so is performing `if` comparisons manually to return 0, 1, or -1.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
];

const { compare } = Intl.Collator('en-US');
arr.sort((a, b) => compare(a.updated_at, b.updated_at));
```

`Intl.Collator` returns a function that can be used as the `compareFunction` for `#Array.sort`. Because we're sorting an object, we call `compare` with the values of the key that we want to sort by.

Note that if we were sorting an array of strings, we could simply do this:

```js
arr.sort(compare);
```

Also note that as others have pointed out, `sort` will mutate the original array. If this is undesirable, you may want to clone it first. In 2021 you can do so as follows:

```js
[...arr].sort((a, b) => compare(a.updated_at, b.updated_at));
```

Comment: This is the only one that works for me as of 12/14/2021! (for anyone else who's banging their heads against the wall)

Comment: How to control the sort order? Ascending / descending...

Comment: nvm found it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46374693/2104976

Comment: This works so beautifully, it deserves another comment! :)

Answer (score 8):

**Data Imported**

```
[
    {
        "gameStatus": "1",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 11:32:04"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:08:24"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "2",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:35:40"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 10:42:53"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "2",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 10:54:09"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "1a2fefb0-5ae2-47eb-82ff-d1b2cc27875a",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:46:22"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "1",
        "userId": "7118ed61-d8d9-4098-a81b-484158806d21",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 10:50:48"
    }
]
```

**FOR Ascending order**

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    var keyA = new Date(a.updated_at),
        keyB = new Date(b.updated_at);
    // Compare the 2 dates
    if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

**Example for Asc Order**

```
[
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 10:42:53"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:08:24"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "2",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:35:40"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "1a2fefb0-5ae2-47eb-82ff-d1b2cc27875a",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:46:22"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "1",
        "userId": "7118ed61-d8d9-4098-a81b-484158806d21",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 10:50:48"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "2",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 10:54:09"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "1",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 11:32:04"
    }
]
```

---

**FOR Descending order**

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    var keyA = new Date(a.updated_at),
        keyB = new Date(b.updated_at);
    // Compare the 2 dates
    if(keyA > keyB) return -1;
    if(keyA < keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

**Example for Desc Order**

```
[
    {
        "gameStatus": "1",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 11:32:04"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "2",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 10:54:09"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "1",
        "userId": "7118ed61-d8d9-4098-a81b-484158806d21",
        "created_at": "2018-12-20 10:50:48"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "1a2fefb0-5ae2-47eb-82ff-d1b2cc27875a",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:46:22"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "2",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:35:40"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 18:08:24"
    },
    {
        "gameStatus": "0",
        "userId": "c02cfb18-ae66-430b-9524-67d9dd8f6a50",
        "created_at": "2018-12-19 10:42:53"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

As for today, answers of @knowbody (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418963/6778546) and @Rocket Hazmat (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837511/6778546) can be combined to provide for ES2015 support and correct date handling:

```
var arr = [{
    "updated_at": "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
];
arr.sort((a, b) => {
   const dateA = new Date(a.updated_at);
   const dateB = new Date(b.updated_at);
   return dateA - dateB;
});
```

Comment: Or as one liner `arr.sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a.updated_at) - new Date(b.updated_at)});`.

Answer (score 3):

Just another, more ***mathematical***, way of doing the same thing but **shorter**:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    var diff = new Date(a.updated_at) - new Date(b.updated_at);
    return diff/(Math.abs(diff)||1);
});
```

or in the slick lambda arrow style:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
    var diff = new Date(a.updated_at) - new Date(b.updated_at);
    return diff/(Math.abs(diff)||1);
});
```

***This method can be done with any numeric input***

Comment: underated answer

Comment: Why normalize the `diff`? JS sort only cares about the sign and zero status of the result, not the actual value. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

Answer (score 3):

As [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837511/5811973) answer's states, you can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

`arr.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a.updated_at) - new Date(b.updated_at)})`

```js
arr = [
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    },
    {
        "updated_at" : "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
];
arr.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a.updated_at) - new Date(b.updated_at)});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **Lodash** utility library to solve this problem (it's quite an efficient library):

```js
const data = [{
    "updated_at": "2012-01-01T06:25:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-09T11:25:13Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": "2012-01-05T04:13:24Z",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]

const ordered = _.orderBy(
  data,
  function(item) {
    return item.updated_at;
  }
);

console.log(ordered)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can find documentation here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by an ISO formatted date can be expensive, unless you limit the clients to the latest and best browsers, which can create the correct timestamp by Date-parsing the string.

If you are **sure** of your input, and you **know** it will always be  yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss and GMT (Z) you can extract the digits from each member and compare them like integers

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.updated_at.replace(/\D+/g,'')-b.updated_at.replace(/\D+/g,'');
});
```

If the date could be formatted differently, you may need to add something for iso challenged folks:

```
Date.fromISO: function(s){
    var day, tz,
    rx=/^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT ][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?$/,
    p= rx.exec(s) || [];
    if(p[1]){
        day= p[1].split(/\D/).map(function(itm){
            return parseInt(itm, 10) || 0;
        });
        day[1]-= 1;
        day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));
        if(!day.getDate()) return NaN;
        if(p[5]){
            tz= (parseInt(p[5], 10)*60);
            if(p[6]) tz+= parseInt(p[6], 10);
            if(p[4]== '+') tz*= -1;
            if(tz) day.setUTCMinutes(day.getUTCMinutes()+ tz);
        }
        return day;
    }
    return NaN;
}
if(!Array.prototype.map){
    Array.prototype.map= function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, L= T.length, A= Array(L), i= 0;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in T){
                    A[i]= fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
                }
                ++i;
            }
            return A;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this we can pass a key function to use for the sorting

```
Array.prototype.sortBy = function(key_func, reverse=false){
    return this.sort( (a, b) => {
        var keyA = key_func(a),
            keyB = key_func(b);
        if(keyA < keyB) return reverse? 1: -1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return reverse? -1: 1;
        return 0;
    }); 
}
```

Then for example if we have

```
var arr = [ {date: "01/12/00", balls: {red: "a8",  blue: 10}},
            {date: "12/13/05", balls: {red: "d6" , blue: 11}},
            {date: "03/02/04", balls: {red: "c4" , blue: 15}} ]
```

We can do

```
arr.sortBy(el => el.balls.red)
/* would result in
[ {date: "01/12/00", balls: {red: "a8", blue: 10}},
  {date: "03/02/04", balls: {red: "c4", blue: 15}},
  {date: "12/13/05", balls: {red: "d6", blue: 11}} ]
*/
```

or

```
arr.sortBy(el => new Date(el.date), true)   // second argument to reverse it
/* would result in
[ {date: "12/13/05", balls: {red: "d6", blue:11}},
  {date: "03/02/04", balls: {red: "c4", blue:15}},
  {date: "01/12/00", balls: {red: "a8", blue:10}} ]
*/
```

or

```
arr.sortBy(el => el.balls.blue + parseInt(el.balls.red[1]))
/* would result in
[ {date: "12/13/05", balls: {red: "d6", blue:11}},    // red + blue= 17
  {date: "01/12/00", balls: {red: "a8", blue:10}},    // red + blue= 18
  {date: "03/02/04", balls: {red: "c4", blue:15}} ]   // red + blue= 19
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort an array
- Clone array using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`…`) to make the function pure
- Sort by desired key (`updated_at`)
- Convert date string to [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- `Array.sort()` works by subtracting two properties from current and next item if it is a number / object on which you can perform arrhythmic operations

```js
const input = [
  {
    updated_at: '2012-01-01T06:25:24Z',
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  {
    updated_at: '2012-01-09T11:25:13Z',
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  {
    updated_at: '2012-01-05T04:13:24Z',
    foo: 'bar',
  }
];

const sortByUpdatedAt = (items) => [...items].sort((itemA, itemB) => new Date(itemA.updated_at) - new Date(itemB.updated_at));

const output = sortByUpdatedAt(input);

console.log(input);
/*
[ { updated_at: '2012-01-01T06:25:24Z', foo: 'bar' }, 
  { updated_at: '2012-01-09T11:25:13Z', foo: 'bar' }, 
  { updated_at: '2012-01-05T04:13:24Z', foo: 'bar' } ]
*/
console.log(output)
/*
[ { updated_at: '2012-01-01T06:25:24Z', foo: 'bar' }, 
  { updated_at: '2012-01-05T04:13:24Z', foo: 'bar' }, 
  { updated_at: '2012-01-09T11:25:13Z', foo: 'bar' } ]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sorting function in Typescript which we can use to search strings, dates and numbers in array of objects. It can also sort on multiple fields.

```
export type SortType = 'string' | 'number' | 'date';
export type SortingOrder = 'asc' | 'desc';

export interface SortOptions {
  sortByKey: string;
  sortType?: SortType;
  sortingOrder?: SortingOrder;
}


class CustomSorting {
    static sortArrayOfObjects(fields: SortOptions[] = [{sortByKey: 'value', sortType: 'string', sortingOrder: 'desc'}]) {
        return (a, b) => fields
          .map((field) => {
            if (!a[field.sortByKey] || !b[field.sortByKey]) {
              return 0;
            }

            const direction = field.sortingOrder === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;

            let firstValue;
            let secondValue;

            if (field.sortType === 'string') {
              firstValue = a[field.sortByKey].toUpperCase();
              secondValue = b[field.sortByKey].toUpperCase();
            } else if (field.sortType === 'number') {
              firstValue = parseInt(a[field.sortByKey], 10);
              secondValue = parseInt(b[field.sortByKey], 10);
            } else if (field.sortType === 'date') {
              firstValue = new Date(a[field.sortByKey]);
              secondValue = new Date(b[field.sortByKey]);
            }
            return firstValue > secondValue ? direction : firstValue < secondValue ? -(direction) : 0;

          })
          .reduce((pos, neg) => pos ? pos : neg, 0);
      }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const sortOptions = [{
      sortByKey: 'anyKey',
      sortType: 'string',
      sortingOrder: 'asc',
    }];

arrayOfObjects.sort(CustomSorting.sortArrayOfObjects(sortOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is a possible short generic implementation of sortBy:

```
function sortBy(list, keyFunc) {
  return list.sort((a,b) => keyFunc(a) - keyFunc(b));
}

sortBy([{"key": 2}, {"key": 1}], o => o["key"])
```

Note that this uses the arrays sort method that sorts in place.
for a copy you can use arr.concat() or arr.slice(0) or similar method to create a copy.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a closure and pass it that way
[here is my example working](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelguild/u96bzj7q/5/)

```
$.get('https://data.seattle.gov/resource/3k2p-39jp.json?$limit=10&$where=within_circle(incident_location, 47.594972, -122.331518, 1609.34)', 
  function(responce) {

    var filter = 'event_clearance_group', //sort by key group name
    data = responce; 

    var compare = function (filter) {
        return function (a,b) {
            var a = a[filter],
                b = b[filter];

            if (a < b) {
                return -1;
            } else if (a > b) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    };

    filter = compare(filter); //set filter

    console.log(data.sort(filter));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I face with same thing, so i handle this with a generic why and i build a function for this:

> ```
> //example:
> //array: [{name: 'idan', workerType: '3'}, {name: 'stas', workerType: '5'}, {name: 'kirill', workerType: '2'}]
> //keyField: 'workerType'
> // keysArray: ['4', '3', '2', '5', '6']
> ```

```
sortByArrayOfKeys = (array, keyField, keysArray) => {
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        const aIndex = keysArray.indexOf(a[keyField])
        const bIndex = keysArray.indexOf(b[keyField])
        if (aIndex < bIndex) return -1;
        if (aIndex > bIndex) return 1;
        return 0;
    })
}
```