# Sorting with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, xml

I would like to parse an xml file and list the elements in a different order than they appears  in the xml. Each child elements have a name and a number value, i would like to list the names but in the order of the number values. The xml file looks similar to this:

```
 <stories>
    <story>
      <name>fast</name>
      <number>1000</number>
    </story>
    <story>
      <name>bomb</name>
      <number>2</number>
    </story>
    <story>
      <name>descend</name>
      <number>500</number>
    </story>
    <story>
      <name>A</name>
      <number>1</number>
    </story>
    <story>
      <name>can</name>
      <number>40</number>
    </story>
    <story>
      <name>extremely</name>
      <number>10000</number>
    </story>
 </stories>
```

update:
and my script looks something like this atm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
testOpen = xmlhttp;
testOpen.open("GET", "test.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
testDoc = testOpen.responseXML;
stories = testDoc.getElementsByTagName("story");
function display(){
    var arrayStory = Array.prototype.slice.call(stories, 0);
    arrayStory.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.getElementsByTagName("number")[0].firstChild.nodeValue - b.getElementsByTagName("number")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    });
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = arrayStory.map(function(story){
        return story.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    }).join("<br>");
};
</script>
```

i've got my listorder working this way. my question would be that, how can i list the numbers(or any additional nodevalue) next to the names (without using tables) and how can i setup conditions/creating sublists in a list like this(if i cannot, please help me create a list where i can), I would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ArunPJohny false, it is synchronous

Comment: So read the elements into an array and perform a sort on that array.

Comment: are you asking us to implement a sorting function for you?

Comment: I couldn't figure out myself any working way so far, my attempts ended up with not showing anything at all about the xml. I posted a sample part of my coding, because if you give me a hint I could use that to reach more child elements.

Comment: Please show us your attempt, so can explain you where the mistake was :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `display` code should do it:

```
var arr = [],
    l = stories.length;
for (var i=0; i<l; i++)
    arr.push( {
        story: stories[i],
        number: parseInt(stories[i]
                           .getElementsByTagName("number")[0]
                           .firstChild.nodeValue, 10)
        // seriosly, an attribute on the <story> element is more appropriate
    } );
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.number - b.number;
});
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = arr.map(function(o) {
    return o.story.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
}).join("<br />");
```

Comment: i couldn't get result with this script, but it did help me to get the listorder working, so thank you very much. i've updated my question and the code above.

Answer (score -2):

I would advice you to use Json instead of XML.

Then you can use the javascript sort() method to sort the JSON using the answer you can find here: [Sort array of objects by single key with date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key)