# sorting 2d array in node js

Tags: node.js, sorting

From the following code I am getting the appropriate output, but I want the data to come in sorted form i.e the most recent data must come on top. The data must be sorted in descending order according to the difference of current date and 'win_date'.I am new to node.js..earlier in PHP I used to do this by using function array_multisort. Can someone suggest the alternative to do the same in nodejs.

```
var post=[];

var sql2 ="SELECT `post_id`, `user_id`, `post`, `votes_count`, `win_date` FROM `tb_winning_posts` WHERE  `group_id`=?";
 connection.query(sql2,[groupId],function(err, result) {

 });

for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
var timeDiff = getTimeDifference(result[i].win_date);   //returns diff of cur date & given   date in day,hour,min
post.push({"post_id":result[i].post_id,"post":result[i].post,"votes":result[i].votes_count,"date":timeDiff}); 

}
console.log(post); //getting the data in order as stored in database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837511/1903116

```
post.sort(function(a, b){
    var keyA = a.date, keyB = b.date;
    if(keyA < keyB) return 1;
    if(keyA > keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});
console.log (post);
```