# How to sort a multidimensional array by name

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

```
var items = [
    {
        "id": 376,
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": 253,
        "name": "f"
    },
    {
        "id": 236,
        "name": "c"
    },
    {
        "id": 235,
        "name": "e"
    },
    {
        "id": 165,
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "d"
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "d"
    }
]
```

How can i sort array by name?

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array. It's an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using strings try

```
items.sort(function (o1, o2) {
    return o1.name.localeCompare(o2.name)
});
console.log(items)
```

- [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example of sorting on a key [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key)

The example given in that answer looks like this:

```
items.sort(function(a, b){
    var keyA = new Date(a.name),
    keyB = new Date(b.name);
    // Compare the 2 dates
    if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: So what's the point of doing copy-paste then rather than marking as duplicate?

Comment: if it were me, i'd prefer the answer to be right under the question i asked. also i changed the name of the key from that question. so relax.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of objects.  You'll need to write your own compare function.

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
  {
      return -1;
  }
  if (a.name > b.name)
  {
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Then sort it like so:

```
items.sort(compare);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function byName(a, b){
  var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
  var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase(); 
  return ((nameA < nameB) ? -1 : ((nameA > nameB) ? 1 : 0));
}

array.sort(byName);
```

More about [.sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code:

```
myarray.sort(function(a, b){
    var keyA = new Date(a.updated_at),
    keyB = new Date(b.updated_at);
    // Compare dates
    if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
    if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This Could Work

```
function SortByName(a, b){
  var aName = a.id;
  var bName = b.id; 
  return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
}

items.sort(SortByName)
```