# insert items to dictionary with reverse forloop (django)

Tags: python, django, data-structures, dictionary

So i have initialized a forloop that iterates over a range of objects, where range starts from 1 and ends at the maximum number of fields a model has

```
for count in range(1, len(field_list)):
    f_val = getattr(instance, field_list[count])
    field_values[field_list[count]] = f_val
    print "field_values: ", field_values
```

The `f_val` variable calculates the field value using `model_instance.field_name` and inserts the field name and field value as key value pairs in 'field_values' dictionary. When i print `field_values` i get:

```
field_values:  {'descr': u'ggg'}
field_values:  {'descr_en': u'sg', 'descr': u'ggg'}
field_values:  {'notes': u'ddddf', 'descr_en': u'sg', 'descr': u'ggg'}
```

so what i want to do now is reverse the order of the key value pairs such that i have `{'descr': u'ggg', 'descr_en': u'sg', 'notes': u'ddddf'}`. Thus, I used `reversed()` in my initial loop (`for count in reversed(range(1, len(field_list))):`) but my dictionary although it started with the last key value pair instead of the first still the final output was the same as in the beginning.

```
field_values:  {'notes': u'ddddf'}
field_values:  {'notes': u'ddddf', 'descr_en': u'sg'}
field_values:  {'notes': u'ddddf', 'descr_en': u'sg', 'descr': u'ggg'}
```

So I would like to know why this is happening?? does it sort my dictionary by default?? And if this approach does not work what other approaches could i follow?

Comment: Dictionary keys are _unordered_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are **unordered** data types indexed by their keys ([documentation found here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)) so it doesn't matter what order you add keys to your `dict`.

There are some great questions on [sorting a dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) and [sorting a dictionary by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key) using [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Though why you'd want to do this other than aesthetics (waste of computation power IMO) I don't know...

Comment: i am doing this in django and i have lots of models with lots of fields and thus i want to render everything in an orderly fashion in my templates. So yeah you could say it is for the aesthetics of organising... to aid the user in identifying the fields more quickly.

Comment: Anyway the anwser you provided was really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah this makes a bit more sense @per7inac1ousQ. One thing you could do is actually return this unordered and then order it client side with Javascript (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key) about ordering objects). This has the ability that the user may be able to order by other keys (if it's in a table or similar for example). Just a thought...

Comment: Indeed that is a nice thought, moving part of the processing on the client side, thus boosting the performance. However, I am more concerned about the reliability of the data (JavaScript is not very dependable on this end) so I will see at a later stage to what extend I will implement this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are unordered, so it doesn't matter what order you insert items into them.

The standard library has an ordered version of the dictionary as well, `collections.OrderedDict`. Maybe you can use that.