# ng-grid: How to define my own sort function in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

The existing **ng-click="col.sort($event)"** just sort by current page,not all data.
I already know the following two parameters. but it can't resolve my problem.
The sortInfo looks like can't define a function.
I want define my own sort function ╮(╯_╰)╭

param0: useExternalSorting
default: false
definition: Prevents the internal sorting from executing. The sortInfo object will be updated with the sorting information so you can handle sorting (see sortInfo)

param1: sortInfo
default: { fields: [], directions: [] } 
definition: Define a sortInfo object to specify a default sorting state. You can also observe this variable to utilize server-side sorting (see useExternalSorting). Syntax is sortInfo: { fields: ['fieldName1',' fieldName2'], directions: ['asc', 'desc']}. Directions are case-insensitive

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. Sorting works for data specified in 'data' option. Column also has an option 'sortFn', so you may override default sorting order.

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128833/nggrid-sort-entire-result-set/25133627#25133627