# Word frequency for array of key/values on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, word-frequency

I'm trying to implement a piece of code on javascript to analyse word/frequency on a given string. My objective is to return a array as the following:

```
[{text: firstword, size:3 },{text:secondword , size:5 },{text: nword, size: 1},...]
```

I implemented the following code but I'm running out of memory, so I don't really know if its ok or not.

```
function wordFrequency(txt){
    var wordArray = txt.split(/[ .?!,*'"]/);
    var newArray = [];
    $.each(wordArray, function (ix, word) {
        if (newArray.length >= 1){
            newArray.some(function (w){
                if (w.text === word){
                    w.size++;
                } else {
                    newArray.push({text: word, size: 1});
                }
            });
        } else {
            newArray.push({text: word, size: 1});
        }
    });
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: It's ok in my console

Comment: but it will have repeated result I tried this one: wordFrequency("negin!kjs$wkjh*df  oiuw& skdjhh");

Comment: I'm trying to use a big chunck of text and Im getting out of memory every time, even when tried with jsfiddle. :(

Comment: because when you have space you shouldn't count it as a word

Comment: just remove the space and try again i mean in here : txt.split(/[ .?!,*'"]/); remove and instead have this: txt.split(/[.?!,*'"]/);

Comment: In addition to my answer running out of memory is a pretty good indicator that your code is **not** ok.

Comment: @diegodacal does the order of the words in the final result actually matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) expects the given callback to return true or false and returns true as soon as your callback returns true for a given element, otherwise it returns false.

So `some` iterates over all elements, with your given callback, and your callback checks if the given element text equals the *search word* and if not adds a new object. Introducing a new element the `some` function can iterate over.

So to make this clear, for every word thats in the `newArray` before the word you're searching, you're adding a new object containing your word.

Suppose your `newArray` looks like this:

`[{word:"test"},{word:"another"},{word:"one"},{word:"more"}]`

after calling your function for the word `even` it looks like this:

`[{word:"test"},{word:"another"},{word:"one"},{word:"more"},{word:"even"},{word:"even"},{word:"even"},{word:"even"}]`

Using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would be the better approach here, finding you the matching element, note that I also replaced `$.each` with [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
function wordFrequency(txt){
  var wordArray = txt.split(/[ .?!,*'"]/);
  var newArray = [], wordObj;
  wordArray.forEach(function (word) {
    wordObj = newArray.filter(function (w){
      return w.text == word;
    });
    if (wordObj.length) {
      wordObj[0].size += 1;
    } else {
      newArray.push({text: word, size: 1});
    }
  });
  return newArray;
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(wordFrequency("count everything, count all the words, count all the words!").sort(function(a,b){return a.size<b.size})).split("},").join("}<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler and *far* more efficient to create a direct map from word to frequency, and only afterwards convert that to your array structure.  Given an array `words` create a map of the words:

```
var freq = words.reduce(function(p, c) {
    p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
    return p;
}, {});
```

and the convert that map into your array:

```
var array = Object.keys(freq).map(function(key) {
   return { text: key, size: freq[key] };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To tell the frequency all you need is a hash map approach. Your algorithm is quadratic, since the `some` method is nested in the `each` method, so you're always looping over the `newArray` just to find an entry and increment the size.

A map approach is easily achievable using a JavaScript object. It also gives you constant look-up time, which is better performance than the nested loops approach.

Try this approach instead:

```
function wordFrequency(txt){
    var wordArray = txt.split(/[ .?!,*'"]/);
    var map = {};
    $.each(wordArray, function(ix, word) {
      // skip empty results
      if (!word.length) {
        return;
      }
      // add word to map
      if (!map[word]) {
        map[word] = 0;
      } 
      map[word]++;
    });
    return map;
}
```

To use the function:

```
var text = "hello!world*hello foo  'bar'foo";
var result = wordFrequency(text);

// iterate over results
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(w) {
  console.log(w + ": " + result[w]);
});

// or use for...in
for (var w in result) {
  console.log(w + ": " + result[w]);
}
```

If you really wanted to, you could then map the result into your desired array format with text and size properties:

```
var mappedResult = Object.keys(result).map(function(w) {
  return { text: w, size: result[w] };
});
console.log(mappedResult);
```

Also, depending on your target browsers, you might consider using the array `forEach` instead of the jQuery `$.each`, similar to what I did with the `Object.keys` portion.

Here's the [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/tifibe/1/).

Comment: It maybe better to use wordArray.forEach(function(word){});

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to avoid any iterations on duplicate elements and keep your results array unique. Since any of the iterators of Array.prototype will include each of the elements, they might not be the ideal solution for this. Sometimes plain old loops do the job best ...
(You may also want to expressively escape any special characters in your regular expression).

```
function wordFrequency(txt) {
    var words = txt.split(/[ \.\?!,\*'"]+/),
        seen = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var w = words[i],
            found = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < seen.length; j++) {
            if (w === seen[j].text) {
                seen[j].size++;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) seen.push( { text: w, size: 1 } );
    }
    return seen;
}
```

(Note that the inner for-loop isn't visited for the first word, so the first word will be pushed to the seen-stack and the inner for-loop will start with the second word compared to the first one. Only words that we haven't seen already are added to the seen-stack, making it an array of unique elements.)

And here is the equivalent using Array.prototype.forEach() and Array.prototype.indexOf(), but we have to add another intermediate results stack for the latter one. So we'll have to add another iteration to produce the final result. (We wouldn't have to do this using Array.prototype.findIndex(), but this is not a standard method.)

```
function wordFrequency2(txt) {
    var words = txt.split(/[ \.\?!,\*'"]+/),
        seen = [],
        freq = [];
    // get frequencies
    words.forEach(function (w) {
        var idx = seen.indexOf(w);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            freq[idx]++;
        }
        else {
            seen.push(w);
            freq.push(1);
        }
    });
    // produce the results array
    var r = [];
    seen.forEach(function (w, idx) {
        r.push( { text: w, size: freq[idx] } );
    });
    return r;
}
```

Putting optimization into account, the first version using explicit loops will be probably performing faster ...

Comment: what on earth are those `seen.push` and `freq.lines` supposed to be doing?!  The latter should be `freq[w] = 1`, and later you can juse use `Object.keys(freq)` to get the list of unique words.

Comment: @Alnitak This was supposing that the order would be of any importance. Since we don't know any of the use case, we're not entitled to discard this information (as would be the case with using associative arrays/hashes). I would have guessed that this would be of relevance, since the problem is quite trivial using object keys. (if (seen[w]) freq[w]++;)

Comment: ok, I understand what you're trying to do now, although as a result you still end up with an `O(n * m)` algorithm.

Comment: You won't really get around this, since even a hash lookup (freq[w]) is the equivalent of an inner loop. It might be more performant, since the hashes might be ordered internally, but there's also a penalty for producing the hash key. For a real big text, we might consider using a b-tree for storing any words seen, but I doubt that this would be a use case for this.

Comment: The problem is not O(n * m/2) but probably "$.each". The loop-version performs in no time without issues on the text-content of this page.

Comment: no, a good hash lookup is `O(1)` and  _not_ the equivalent of an inner loop.  In JS an object property lookup is highly optimised.

Comment: I really don't think that this is an issue here, for I doubt that a problem addressed in JS would involve large quantities of data. Besides, I'm using hashes for similar problems myself. Anyway, the algorithm presented in the question is maintaining the initial order of words as they occur in the text and is encountering an out-of-memory problem. This is, what is addressed here, without altering any of the specs of the initial algorithm. (Please mind that an object has an even a bigger memory footprint and requires maintaining a b-tree.)

Answer (score -1):

```
var words = (function(){

var sWords = document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[,;.]/g,'').split(/[\s\/]+/g).sort();
var iWordsCount = sWords.length; // count w/ duplicates

// array of words to ignore
var ignore = ['and','the','to','a','of','for','as','i','with','it','is','on','that','this','can','in','be','has','if'];
ignore = (function(){
var o = {}; // object prop checking > in array checking
var iCount = ignore.length;
for (var i=0;i<iCount;i++){
o[ignore[i]] = true;
}
return o;
}());

var counts = {}; // object for math
for (var i=0; i<iWordsCount; i++) {
var sWord = sWords[i];
if (!ignore[sWord]) {
counts[sWord] = counts[sWord] || 0;
counts[sWord]++;
}
}

var arr = []; // an array of objects to return
for (sWord in counts) {
arr.push({
text: sWord,
frequency: counts[sWord]
});
}

// sort array by descending frequency | http://stackoverflow.com/a/8837505
return arr.sort(function(a,b){
return (a.frequency > b.frequency) ? -1 : ((a.frequency < b.frequency) ? 1 : 0);
});

}());

(function(){
var iWordsCount = words.length; // count w/o duplicates
for (var i=0; i<iWordsCount; i++) {
var word = words[i];
console.log(word.frequency, word.text);
}
}());
```