# JavaScript - error on first run, second run is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a rather large script that will be executed from the console while on a specific page --

It basically has 3 parts

1) ajax request to grab HTML from another page then create array from desired data pulled out of the HTML

2) scan current page for all words, ignoring words from step 1, create array with all words that werent ignored

3)not there yet but will be simple after I get this question figured out

When I run it once from the console I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
```

If I hit up arrow then enter and run the script a second time, it goes through step 1 and 2 perfectly like I want.

Is this due to the ajax request not being finished when step 2 asks for the array?

```
var myFilter;
var dynamicExclude;
var arrDynamicExclude;
var staticExclude = ['are', 'is', 'where', 'was'];
var mergedExclude;
var words;
var word;
var ignore;
var finalList;

var stepOne = function () {
    //.unique
    Array.prototype.unique = function () {
        var a = this.concat();
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
            for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
                if(a[i] === a[j])
                    a.splice(j--, 1);
            }
        }
        return a;
    };
    // request HTML from wikipedia most common words
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
                dynamicExclude = $.map($(data).find('.wikitable tr'), function(el, index) {
                return $(el).find('td:last').text() || null;
            });
            mergedExclude = dynamicExclude.concat(staticExclude).unique();
        }
    });
//->
    console.log("step 1");
}

var stepTwo = function () {
    // modified from: http://iamnotagoodartist.com/web/quick-and-dirty-word-frequency-analysis-with-javascript/
   var words = (function(){
        var sWords = document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[,;.]/g,'').split(/[\s\/]+/g).sort();
        // count w/ duplicates
        var iWordsCount = sWords.length;
        // array of words to ignore
        var ignore = mergedExclude;
        var ignore = (function(){
            // object prop checking > in array checking
            var o = {};
            var iCount = ignore.length;
            for (var i=0;i<iCount;i++){
                o[ignore[i]] = true;
            }
            return o;
        }());
        //do not allow words that are 1 chracter or non-alpha characters
        function myValidate(word) {
            return (word.length === 1 || /[^A-Z]/i.test(word)) ? true : false;
        }
        // object for math
        var counts ={};
        for (var i=0; i<iWordsCount; i++) {
            var sWord = sWords[i];
            if (!ignore[sWord] && !myValidate(sWord)) {
                counts[sWord] = counts[sWord] || 0;
                counts[sWord]++;
            }
        }
        // an array of objects to return
        var arr = [];
        for (sWord in counts) {
            arr.push({
                text: sWord,
                frequency: counts[sWord]
            });
        }
        // sort array by descending frequency | http://stackoverflow.com/a/8837505
        return arr.sort(function(a,b){
            return (a.frequency > b.frequency) ? -1 : ((a.frequency < b.frequency) ? 1 : 0);
        });
    }());
    (function(){
        // count w/o duplicates
        var iWordsCount = words.length;
        for (var i=0; i<iWordsCount; i++) {
            var word = words[i];
            //console.log(word.frequency, word.text);
        }
    }());
    var finalList =[];
    finalList = words.slice(0, 25);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(finalList));
//->
        console.log("step 2");
}

var stepThree = function(){
//->
        console.log("step 3");
}
//put the steps into the run queue
var runQueue = [stepOne,stepTwo,stepThree];
//run through the steps, removing the step from the queue after running
while (runQueue.length){
    runQueue.shift().call();
}
```

Comment: Which line of code in which JS file the error is occurring?

Comment: you need to post the code, its likely the async of the ajax call, but we cant tell for sure

Comment: added code, i believe its happening 

`var iCount = ignore.length;`

Comment: also any suggestions for cleanup/optimizing would be great :)

Comment: btw to execute it, just paste the whole code in the console while on ANY wikipedia page

Comment: the ajax success function call happens asynchronously. So you might be running this line `var ignore = mergedExclude;` before mergedExclude has a value.

Comment: @David784 this is what I was thinking, however I am unsure how to account for that

Comment: Could you call stepTwo (and possibly stepThree) from your ajax success function?

Comment: that does work -- not sure if its the best way of handling but it definitely works!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the following line of code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
                dynamicExclude = $.map($(data).find('.wikitable tr'), function(el, index) {
                return $(el).find('td:last').text() || null;
            });
         HERE   mergedExclude = dynamicExclude.concat(staticExclude).unique();
        }
    });
```

you no longer have access to `dynamicExclude` outside of the success function. And hence the

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)
```

I cut that one line and it went through and logged the stuff from step 1.

Picture as proof: all I did was remove that line...

[image]

Comment: Did not work, I am setting mergedExclude to include both dynamicExclude and staticExclude while in the success function, so I can use it outside of the success function

is this incorrect?

Comment: Why doesn't he have access to them? Looks like he is declaring both mergedExclude and dynamicExclude as global variables. In fact it looks like he has declared just about everything as a global variable. I think it's more likely an async issue

Comment: have to refresh the page between runs, it works fine on the 2nd run.

Comment: its because when he gets the data it is asynchronous, it comes back AFTER he sets it so when it gets to that part of the code, its still just the variable he set up at the top, which is undefined, if he set that variable to and empty array, this error doesnt happen, but it still wont do what he wants