# Intl.Collator descending order sort

Tags: javascript

Given this example:

```
let a = ['New York', 'New Hampshire', 'Maryland'];
let collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
a.sort(collator.compare);
```

How might this array be sorted in descending order?

Answer (score 11):

You can switch the parameters:

```
a.sort( (x, y) => collator.compare(y, x) )
```

or sort and reverse:

```
a.sort(collator.compare).reverse()
```

Comment: Good answer. It is too bad that you cannot specify "descending" via the options object of the collator's constructor. This would produce a collator that sorts descending inherently (without the need of wrapping the collator.compare function inside another function).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `reverse`:

```js
let a = ['New York', 'New Hampshire', 'Maryland'];
a.reverse();

console.log(a)
```

Or you can loop through `a` array and `unshift` each item to new array:

```js
let a = ['New York', 'New Hampshire', 'Maryland'];
let b = [];
a.forEach((item) => {
  b.unshift(item);
})

console.log(b)
```