# how to display/differentiate data from json response

Tags: json, typescript, for-loop, datatables, iteration

I have following dynamic response in `JSON`, so I have one list object and I want to display and differentiate data using form_id. please tell me how to achieve this...

```
//list object
formsSummery: any = [];

this.formsSummery = (data[0] as any).data_points;

   [ {
  "job" : 10,
  "data_points" : [ {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-26T13:17:33.489Z",
    "form_id" : 2,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "2.2",
    "field2" : "two",
    "field3" : "2",
    "field4" : "1"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-26T13:03:56.757Z",
    "form_id" : 7,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "thirteen",
    "field2" : "fourteen",
    "field3" : "fifteen",
    "field4" : "sixteen"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-27T11:58:59.735Z",
    "form_id" : 7,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "17",
    "field2" : "TWENTY",
    "field3" : "19",
    "field4" : "1",
    "field5master" : "EIGHTEEN",
    "field6" : "TRUE"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-26T07:23:26.468Z",
    "form_id" : 7,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "five",
    "field2" : "seven",
    "field3" : "six",
    "field4" : "eight"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-26T07:24:14.729Z",
    "form_id" : 7,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "nine",
    "field2" : "eleven",
    "field3" : "ten",
    "field4" : "twele"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-26T08:29:36.728Z",
    "form_id" : 2,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "2.1",
    "field2" : "one",
    "field3" : "1",
    "field4" : "true"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-26T07:18:10.401Z",
    "form_id" : 7,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "one",
    "field2" : "three",
    "field3" : "two",
    "field4" : "four"
  }, {
    "user_id" : 11,
    "ingest_time" : "2017-09-27T11:57:06.188Z",
    "form_id" : 2,
    "form_revision" : 1,
    "device_id" : 0,
    "field1" : "2.3",
    "field2" : "THREE",
    "field3" : "3",
    "field4" : "TRUE"
  } ]
} ]
```

I want to display data using `form_id`.
I want to display data in the table using form_id (all arrays for form_d=7 in one table) like this, and a number of table = number of form ids.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _I want to display and differentiate data using form_id._ ? Do you want to filter your data? Under what criteria?

Comment: Yes! I want to filter using form_id property

Comment: But if there are multiple objects with the same `form_id`, what do you want to happen to your data? Do you want to keep the newest object, keep the oldest object, something else ... ?

Comment: I want the newest object.

Comment: And when you say newest object, you're referring to the `ingest_time`, right? This would be much easier if your data were ordered by date. I would suggest starting there, then using `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: Yes ingest_time! thanks! can you please provide some code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first ordering your `data_points` array, with something like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value#answer-8837511). Then use a `Set` to keep track of the `form_id's` in your array. As you filter, if the `form_id` is already in your `Set`, you'll ignore it.

Example:

```
let x = new Set();
const y = this.formsSummery[0].data_points.filter(z => {
  return !x.has(z.form_id) ? x.add(z.form_id) : null
})
```

So if `!x.has(z.form_id)` evaluates to `true`, `x.add(z.form_id)` will be returned, which will also evaluate to `true` - and the desired object will be added to your filtered array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOvRY.jpg)

Comment: Actually, I am getting EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Ok, so accessing the array is slightly off.  Can you post the entire response object? Maybe a screenshot of a console.log?

Comment: It looks like your response has been _stringified_. Try creating a variable: `const obj = JSON.parse(response)`. Then do your filtering on the new variable.

Comment: See attached picture

Comment: if I used like this const y = JSON.parse(response[0] as any).data_points.filter 
theh
EXCEPTION: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Now, I got like this: x data:{}
current-activity.component.ts:523 y data:[{"user_id":11,"ingest_time":"2017-09-26T13:17:33.489Z","form_id":2,"form_revision":1,"device_id":0,"field1":"2.2","field2":"two","field3":"2","field4":"1"},{"user_id":11,"ingest_time":"2017-09-26T13:03:56.757Z","form_id":7,"form_revision":1,"device_id":0,"field1":"thirteen","field2":"fourteen","field3":"fifteen","field4":"sixteen"}]

Comment: And that's what you were looking for, right? Your original form_ids were 2 & 7. Those objects have the newest `ingest_time` among all the objects.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly I looking ...Thanks a lot @bazzells

Comment: Nice, glad it worked. Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: My one problem is solved! Next, I want to display data in the table using form_id (all arrays for form_d=7 in one table) like this, and a number of table = number of form ids.

Comment: Is it possible? or not

Comment: You could start with your array of objects created previously. Then create an object that has a key for each form_id, like this: const baseObj = y.reduce((obj, cur) => obj[form_id] = !obj.hasOwnProperty(cur.form_id) ? [] : obj[form_id], {}). Here, baseObj would be something like: {2:[], 7:[]}. Then, do a reduce on formsSummery and populate those empty arrays with the objects for that form_id. const tables = formsSummery[0].data_points.reduce((obj,cur) => { obj[cur.form_id].push(cur); return obj; }, baseObj); . Note: this isn't tested but should be a good starting point.

Comment: Rough draft ^, could possibly do in one pass, but a starting point nonetheless.

Comment: I have tried this but I got empty baseObj. could you please provide some working code for this.Please!

Comment: HI @bazzells please help me one more time...Please

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ret = 0
    function filter(filterId) {
      data = formsSummery[0].data_points;
      for (i in data) {
        if (data[i].form_id == filterId) {

          if (ret != 0 && (new Date(data[i].ingest_time).getTime()) >= (new Date(ret.ingest_time).getTime())) {
            ret = (data[i]);
          }
          else {
            ret = (data[i])
          }
        }
      }
      return ret;
    }
    var result = filter(2) //your filter id 
    console.log(result)
```

not sure about date time