# How to display certain items first in Angular *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have an array with items, one of the fields is 'status' which value can be 'locked' or 'unlocked'.

When I do an *ngFor,

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{item.name}}
</li>
```

I want items with status 'locked' to be displayed first.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Try this Q&A for sort your array by `status` key : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `pipe` which handles the sorting of your items.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({name: 'sortItems'})
export class SortItemsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[]): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    
    const sortedItems = items.sort((itemA, itemB) => {
      if (itemA.status === 'locked' && itemB.status === 'unlocked') {
        return 1;
      } else if (itemA.status === 'unlocked' && itemB.status === 'locked') {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    
    return sortedItems
    
  }
}
```

Declare `SortItemsPipe` in your `module` and use it like this in your template:

```js
<li *ngFor="let item of items | sortItems">
  {{item.name}}
</li>
```

For now on all items with status unlocked will come first.

Comment: Sorting pipes are discouraged by Angular for performance reasons. It's better to sort the array in the component and store the sorted array for display.