# How to sort the following array based on distance in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
array: [
  {
    distance: "4 km",
    name: "A",
    AmountDue: 58576,
    OrderValue: 0,
    Visited: "",
  },
  {
    distance: "10.3 km",
    name: "B",
    AmountDue: 58576,
    OrderValue: 0,
    Visited: "",
  },
  {
    distance: "8 km",
    name: "C",
    AmountDue: 58576,
    OrderValue: 0,
    Visited: "",
  }
]
```

How to sort the above array in ascending order based on distance field. Please help. I am stuck in this

Comment: do you have other units as *km*?

Comment: Yes, meters and KM

Comment: Thanks, , It worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the distance as numerical value and sort by the delta of it.

```js
const
    getDistance = string => 
        (([number, unit]) => number * { km: 1000, m: 1 }[unit])
        (string.split(' '));

var data = [{ distance: "4 km", name: 'A', AmountDue: 58576, OrderValue: 0, Visited: "" }, { distance: "10.3 km", name: 'B', AmountDue: 58576, OrderValue: 0, Visited: "" }, { distance: "8 km", name: 'C', AmountDue: 58576, OrderValue: 0, Visited: "" }, { distance: "2 m", name: 'A', AmountDue: 58576, OrderValue: 0, Visited: "" }];

data.sort((a, b) => getDistance(a.distance) - getDistance(b.distance));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and try something like this:

```
function compare( a, b ) {
      if ( a.distance < b.distance ){
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a.distance > b.distance ){
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }

array.sort( compare );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the character part with empty string, convert it to `Number` and then use the `sort` function.

In a nutshell,

```
array.sort((a, b) => Number(a.distance.replace('km','')) > Number(b.distance.replace('km','')) ? 1 : -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible you could convert the distance to a number on the server. Otherwise use parseFloat(). It will ignore the 'km' part.

When other units come into play you will have to parse it with regex and convert to a single unit. Meters for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `sort()` method. Try like this.

```
array.sort((a,b)=> {return a.distance.split(' ')[0] - b.distance.split(' ')[0] });
```

Answer (score 0):

See you are here trying to sort ***distance*** (probably ascending order). But distance is of type `string` thus making it difficult to sort.

One approach is to make a change in your API and make the distance as a `integer` type. Best will be to convert the distance into ***meters*** instead of ***kilometers***.

Now solving your question.

1) There is an error in your objects. There should be a ***,*** after `distance: "4 km"` and `distance: "10.3 km"` and `distance: "8 km"`

2) We can user [sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) to sort based on distance.

`userArr.sort((a,b)=> {return a.distance.split(' ')[0] - b.distance.split(' ')[0] });`

where userArr is your array of objects.

3) Since distance is in string format, we need to extract the numeric part from the string. We can user [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

For reference read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815997/11926970

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't really sort an object.
However, you can log all of your existing distances and then based on distance count, filter the array in a for loop. In order to avoid logging the same distance if you have the same distance in 2 objects you'd need a unique identificator on each set (like the name) to identify it by and remove it from the array, I've added such a process in my example which is  why i added object D.

When using multiple distances you can detect this via string.includes("km") and just multiply distances that contain the trigger "km". Which means you'd have to parse the numbers first since you supply them as string.

```
let my = {
    array: [
    {
        distance: "4 km",
        name: 'A',
        AmountDue: 58576,
        OrderValue: 0,
        Visited: ""
    },
    {
        distance: "10.3 km",
        name: 'B',
        AmountDue: 58576,
        OrderValue: 0,
        Visited: ""
    },
    {
        distance: "8 km",
        name: 'C',
        AmountDue: 58576,
        OrderValue: 0,
        Visited: ""
    },
    {
        distance: "8 km",
        name: 'D',
        AmountDue: 12346,
        OrderValue: 0,
        Visited: ""
    }]
}
console.log(my.array)
sorter(my)

function sorter(my)
{
    array = my.array;
    distances = []
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        distances.push(array[i].distance.split(" ")[0])
    }
    distances.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        return a - b
    });
    newarray = []
    for (i = 0; i < distances.length; i++)
    {
        newarray.push(array.filter(e => e.distance.split(" ")[0] == distances[i])[0])
        array = array.filter(f => f.name != array.filter(e => e.distance.split(" ")[0] == distances[i])[0].name)
    }
    console.log(newarray)
}
```