# Reorder array of objects by key with one at a fixed position and update its siblings key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects and each object *can* have a `order` prop. Now I want to reorder this array by updating one objects order number. Its siblings should then get updated so that its order makes sense again.

Base:

- 01: no order
- 02: order 4
- 03: order 2
- 04: no order

Steps if `04` get fixed position `2`:

Step 1

- 01: order 0
- 02: order 4
- 03: order 2
- 04: no order

Step 2

- 01: order 0
- 03: order 2
- 04: no order
- 02: order 4

Step 3

- 01: order 0
- 03: order 1
- 04: no order
- 02: order 4

Step 4

- 01: order 0
- 03: order 1
- 04: order 2
- 02: order 4

Step 5

- 01: order 0
- 03: order 1
- 04: order 2
- 02: order 3

With the case when `04` gets a fixed position of `1`, `02` would be on the same index so since `04` is fixed `02` get `04` old index or current + 1.

Comment: How do you decide if `03` gets pushed down to order 1 or up to order 3? How do you decide to order the elements that have `no order`?

Comment: Sounds like normal sorting by key, or did I miss something? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8837454/5520354

Comment: @JannesCarpentier based on their index. 02 gets shifted to the end so 03 gets index 1 and 04 index 2.

Comment: No @C14L, because I want to update the order property of all siblings AND keep the index of 04 at 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

1. You update the order of an element
2. You sort them
3. You update the order values

```js
const data = [{
  i: 1,
  order: "no order"
}, {
  i: 2,
  order: 4
}, {
  i: 3,
  order: 2
}, {
  i: 4,
  order: "no order"
}];

function printData() {
  data.forEach(x => console.log(x.i, x.order));
}

function changeOrderAndSort(index, order) {
  data[index].order = order;
  printData();

  data.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  console.log("--")
  printData();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].order = i;
  }
  console.log("--")
  printData();
}

changeOrderAndSort(3, 2);
```

Comment: That works pretty good, thank you. Just noticed that giving `3` an index of `0` does not work. Will try to build on that.

Comment: That is because I just change its order value, not placing it at a certain index. Also the object with `order: "no order"` will not be moved by the sort function.