# sort array based on month

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

I was trying to do,but i was unable to sort it...I want to sort  the data and year in the below output...  someone help me to solve in nodejs or in javascript.

```
var dataCollection = [
        {
            "data": {
                "Oct-2020": 483
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "Nov-2020": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "Mar-2020": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "Apr-2020": 4
            }
        },
         
    ]
```

**I need to sort this array based on the month like**

```
[{
        "data": {
            "Mar-2020": 8
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
              "Apr-2020": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "Oct-2020": 483
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
             "Nov-2020": 5
        }
    },

]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort()` + some "magic" to convert the date into something that can easily be compared.

Comment: can you pls send me the full version of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by single key with date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value)

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the key of `data` and get the numerical value for month and sort by the delta of month and year.

```js
var dataCollection = [{ data: { "Oct-2018": 483 } }, { data: { "Nov-2020": 5  } }, { data: { "Mar-2020": 8  } }, { data: { "Apr-2020": 4 } }],
    month = { Jan: 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3, Apr: 4, Mey: 5, Jun: 6, Jul: 7, Aug: 8, Sep: 9, Oct: 10, Nov: 11, Dec: 12 };

dataCollection.sort(({ data: a }, { data: b}) => {
    const
        [mA, yA] = Object.keys(a)[0].split('-'),
        [mB, yB] = Object.keys(b)[0].split('-');

    return yA - yB || month[mA] - month[mB];
});

console.log(dataCollection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: since it is giving the wrong output

Comment: You forgot to define April in your month object

Comment: it was edited meanwhile

Comment: i want sort month and the year bro... if we given as Apr-2021 means both the April is next to next... I want to sort based on month and the year

Comment: No bro, sorting a year doesn't work

Comment: right. sorry. please see edit.