# trying to sort bookings by date and hours react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this my first post in StackOverflow, so sorry if I am not posting properly.

Here's my problem, as the title says I want to sort my bookings by date and hour, but the problem I am facing is that the bookings appears in order you create them.

this is the chunk of code:

```
<Card className="my-4 booking-profile">
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>
                        {bookings.map((booking, index) => {
                            console.log(index);
                            return (
                                <ul key={booking.id}>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>
                                            {" "}
                                            Tu reserva: {booking.day}/{booking.month}/{booking.year} a las{" "}
                                            {booking.hour}:{booking.minutes}
                                        </span>
                                        <i
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                deleteBooking(index);
                                            }}
                                            className="fas fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Card.Title>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the booking array ?

Comment: You'll need to sort the array by the dates and then print them.    
Look for an example on how to sort array of objects by key
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837454/sort-array-of-objects-by-single-key-with-date-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with your own custom sorter, say `bookingSorter()`

We'll use the JavaAcript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to help us sort the values, creating a new Date object for each booking, then comparing it to the others in the sort function.

```js
const bookings = [
    { year: 2021, month: 12, day: 20, hour: 07, minutes: 30 },
    { year: 2021, month: 11, day: 4, hour: 15, minutes: 20 },
    { year: 2021, month: 11, day: 9, hour: 16, minutes: 20 },
    { year: 2021, month: 11, day: 4, hour: 15, minutes: 25 }
];

function getBookingDate({ year, month, day, hour, minutes}) {
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minutes);
}

function bookingSorter(a, b) {
    return getBookingDate(a) - getBookingDate(b);
}

function formatBooking(booking) {
    return getBookingDate(booking).toLocaleString('sv');
}


const sortedBookings = [...bookings].sort(bookingSorter);

console.log('Unsorted bookings:', bookings.map(formatBooking));    
console.log('Sorted bookings:', sortedBookings.map(formatBooking))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort it but the problem is that you cant compare day of the week so you need to assign value to each day, you can add another sort for the month and repeat the same process like this:

```
const sorter = {
  //"sunday": 0, // << if sunday is first day of week
  "monday": 1,
  "tuesday": 2,
  "wednesday": 3,
  "thursday": 4,
  "friday": 5,
  "saturday": 6,
  "sunday": 7
}

{bookings.sort(function sortByDay(a, b) {
  let day1 = a.day.toLowerCase();
  let day2 = b.day.toLowerCase();
  return sorter[day1] - sorter[day2];
}).map((booking, index) => { ...
```

Then for the time (hours and minutes) it depends if you are using am pm format or not but the process is the same.