# I want to sort a json and put it in a for loop to list on web, how can I do?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom, for-loop

1. I have a json

   `var Model = {
     listAll: function() {
       var boxes = [{
         you:'128';
         him:'250';
         me:'56'
       }, {
         you:'72';
         him:'8';
         me:'101'
       }, {
         you:'224';
         him:'97';
         me:'35'
       }, {
         you:'81';
         him:'35';
         me:'688'
       }];
       return boxes;

     }
   };`
2. and I want to SORT it according to property "him" ascendingly.
3. then I want to throw it in a "for" loop to list all the data of the json ascendingly accordingly to "him" on webpage. The code goes like this:

   <% for(var i=0; i
    <%= boxes.him %>
    <%= boxes.you %>
    <%= boxes.me %>
    
    <% } %>

Can anyone teach me how to do it?

Comment: Show us what you tried, can you post your code so far and a demo to reproduce your particular issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Please note that the data you have is **not** JSON, it's a normal JavaScript object. Your question has **nothing** to do with JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175093/simple-function-to-sort-a-json-object-using-javascript/8175221#8175221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, and you have an example of "for" loop.

```
var Model = {
    listAll: function () {
        var boxes = [{
            you: '128',
            him: '250',
            me: '56'
        }, {
            you: '72',
            him: '8',
            me: '101'
        }, {
            you: '224',
            him: '97',
            me: '35'
        }, {
            you: '81',
            him: '35',
            me: '688'
        }];

        return boxes;
    }
};

var sortByHim = function (a, b) {
  return a.him - b.him;
}

var sortedList = Model.listAll().sort(sortByHim);

for (var i = 0; i < sortedList.length; i++){
  console.log(sortedList[i].him);
}
```

Comment: I have worked it out!Thank you for your pointer :) ,still thanks for other friends' kindly advises!!

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in that JSON, values shouldn't be terminated with ";" but ",". Here is working example that extends your model and returns sorted list:

```
var Model = {
  listAll: function() {
    var boxes = [{
      you:'128',
      him:'250',
      me:'56'
    }, {
      you:'72',
      him:'8',
      me:'101'
    }, {
      you:'224',
      him:'97',
      me:'35'
    }, {
      you:'81',
      him:'35',
      me:'688'
    }];
    return boxes;
  },
  listSorted: function() {
    var sortedBoxes = this.listAll();
    return sortedBoxes.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a['him'] - b['him'];
    });
  }
};
console.log(Model.listSorted());
```

Comment: *"You have errors in that JSON"*: It's not even JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling right, but thats another question .. I just showed how to sort it as requested :)

Comment: Sure, but you shouldn't use wrong terminology. Other, probably less experienced, users will read your answer and then adapt the incorrect use of the term "JSON" as well.

Comment: You're right .. I still didn't have my morning coffee, my mistake